# Converting these types of unicode to UTF8 in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to convert this in to readable UTF8 text in PHP

```
Tel Aviv-Yafo (Hebrew: \u05ea\u05b5\u05bc\u05dc\u05be\u05d0\u05b8\u05d1\u05b4\u05d9\u05d1-\u05d9\u05b8\u05e4\u05d5\u05b9; Arabic: \u062a\u0644 \u0623\u0628\u064a\u0628\u200e, Tall \u02bcAb\u012bb), usually called Tel Aviv
```

Any ideas on how to do so?

Tried several methods online, but couldn't find one.

In this case I have unicode in Hebrew and Arabic

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha

Answer (score 8):

None of the other answers work perfectly as is.
I've combined them together and my addition results in this one:

```
$replacedString = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9abcdef]{4})/", "&#x$1;", $originalString);
$unicodeString = mb_convert_encoding($replacedString, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

This one definitely does work :)

Comment: I must mention that using mb_convert_encoding() method will convert any &quot; in the original string into " because it involves parsing HTML!!! beware

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem recently, so was glad to see this question. 
Doing some tests, I found the following code works:

```
$replacedString = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9abcdef]{4})/", "&#x$1;", $original_string);
//$unicodeString    = mb_convert_encoding($replacedString, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

The only thing I changed is that I commented out the 2nd line of code. 
Webpage, however, must be set to display UTF-8.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't always work, because /uXXXX code sometimes can contain digits AND letters. 
try replacing \d (just digits) with \w (\w matches both words and digits).

```
function unicode_conv($originalString) {
  // The four \\\\ in the pattern here are necessary to match \u in the original string
  $replacedString = preg_replace("/\\\\u(\w{4})/", "&#$1;", $originalString);
  $unicodeString = mb_convert_encoding($replacedString, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
  return $unicodeString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php#88611) for a way to get a unicode character from its numerical code. Then, you could write a regex replace that will replace each `\uXXXX` pattern with the equivalent character.

Alternatively, you could replace each `\uXXXX` pattern with its matching `&#XXXX;` html entity form, and then use the following:

```
mb_convert_encoding(string_with_html_entities, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

More complete example:

```
// The four \\\\ in the pattern here are necessary to match \u in the original string
$replacedString = preg_replace("/\\\\u(\d{4})/", "&#$1;", $originalString);
$unicodeString = mb_convert_encoding($replacedString, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

Comment: Could you give me an example?

I didn't understand the example in the link.

Say I have this string "\u05ea" somewhere in the text - how would I change it to its html entity form as its not "&#05ea;" or the first option you mentioned.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure, I added a more complete example to my answer.

Comment: @Dav: Why `\\\\u`? Isn't `\\u` enough? I also think that `\d{2,4}` would make it more complete.

Comment: Alix: `\u` would be interpreted by the regex engine as an escape-code u, sort of like how `\d` is the set of digits, and `\w` is the set of "word" characters. Thus you need to actually escape the slash in the *regex*, which means your regex needs to be `\\u`, and then you have to escape those slashes since they're within the string, thus you have \\\\ as the escaped form of \\.

Answer (score 1):

You should add 'x' after '#' in replacement string to indicate that hexadecimal numbers are used.

```
$replacedString = preg_replace("/\\\\u(\d{4})/", "&#x$1;", $originalString);
$unicodeString = mb_convert_encoding($replacedString, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple and beautiful solution.

If we want to decode Unicode escape sequences like `"\u05bc\u05dc"` to `"ל"` we may use simple function `json_decode`:

`$a="Tel Aviv-Yafo (Hebrew: \u05ea\u05b5\u05bc\u05dc\u05be\u05d0\u05b8\u05d1\u05b4\u05d9\u05d1-\u05d9\u05b8\u05e4\u05d5\u05b9; Arabic: \u062a\u0644 \u0623\u0628\u064a\u0628\u200e, Tall \u02bcAb\u012bb), usually called Tel Aviv";`

```php
echo json_decode("\"$a\"");
```

output:

`Tel Aviv-Yafo (Hebrew: תֵּל־אָבִיב-יָפוֹ; Arabic: تل أبيب‎, Tall ʼAbīb), usually called Tel Aviv`

---

It works because `json_encode` encodes all non utf-8 symbols to `\u****` sequence:

```php
echo json_encode("תֵּל");
# output: "\u05ea\u05b5\u05bc\u05dc"
```