# How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, escaping, decoding

Is there a function in PHP that can decode Unicode escape sequences like "`\u00ed`" to "`í`" and all other similar occurrences?

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045058/converting-these-types-of-unicode-to-utf8-in-php/2045105#2045105) but is doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}, $str);
```

In case it's UTF-16 based C/C++/Java/Json-style:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
}, $str);
```

Comment: @Docstero: The regular expression will match any sequence of `\u` followed by four hexadecimal digits.

Comment: Warning: preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \U, or \u at offset 1

Comment: This function cannot deal with supplementary characters as they cannot be represented in UCS-2.

Comment: I wrapped this into a one-parameter function to make it more convenient:
   `<?php function unicode_js_unescape($str) { 
 return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i',
  function($match) {
   return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
  },
  $str);
} ?>`

Comment: @MrFusion - Just fyi, since a lot of people may be interested in using this to correct json_decode output before the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option became available in 5.4.  Your anonymous function will only work in 5.3+.  So there's a pretty small window of versions where it would work and be useful for that specific problem.

Comment: You could of course use 'create_function', but that would be using eval, which I'm sure nobody here would ever do.

Comment: Gumbo you are just great. I have being struggling with this problem for hours.

Comment: This is nice but for older PHP i get T_FUNCTION error because of this function inside function. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @gumbo How do you call or use this function?

Comment: This helps so much! A shame it doesn't capture supplementary characters with the new iOS 10 emoticons, but it's damn close!

Comment: The json_decode function below works far better, clear concise, and fast.

Comment: I found my way here as I had \u00ed in my output, but I was looking at the output with json_encode() and funnily enough the default json_encode() will trash up the output  so use json_encode($theDict,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: This is an outdated code that doesn't work for `surrogate pair` Unicode chars, such as . Here's the code that worked for me instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975110/843732

Answer (score 84):

```
print_r(json_decode('{"t":"\u00ed"}')); // -> stdClass Object ( [t] => í )
```

Comment: It doesn't even need the object wrapper: `json_decode('"' . $text . '"')`

Comment: Thanks. **This seems to be STANDARD WAY**, rather then accepted answer.

Comment: Interestingly, this also works for complex entities like smiley faces... `json_decode('{"t":"\uD83D\uDE0A"}')` is 

Comment: @deceze you should include the fact that `$text` can include double quotes. So a revised version would be: `json_decode('"'.str_replace('"', '\\"', $text).'"')`. Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 25):

### PHP 7+

As of PHP 7, you can use the [Unicode codepoint escape syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax) to do this.

`echo "\u{00ed}";` outputs `í`.

Answer (score 18):

```
$str = '\u0063\u0061\u0074'.'\ud83d\ude38';
$str2 = '\u0063\u0061\u0074'.'\ud83d';

// U+1F638
var_dump(
    "cat\xF0\x9F\x98\xB8" === escape_sequence_decode($str),
    "cat\xEF\xBF\xBD" === escape_sequence_decode($str2)
);

function escape_sequence_decode($str) {

    // [U+D800 - U+DBFF][U+DC00 - U+DFFF]|[U+0000 - U+FFFF]
    $regex = '/\\\u([dD][89abAB][\da-fA-F]{2})\\\u([dD][c-fC-F][\da-fA-F]{2})
              |\\\u([\da-fA-F]{4})/sx';

    return preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) {

        if (isset($matches[3])) {
            $cp = hexdec($matches[3]);
        } else {
            $lead = hexdec($matches[1]);
            $trail = hexdec($matches[2]);

            // http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-4
            $cp = ($lead << 10) + $trail + 0x10000 - (0xD800 << 10) - 0xDC00;
        }

        // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629#section-3
        // Characters between U+D800 and U+DFFF are not allowed in UTF-8
        if ($cp > 0xD7FF && 0xE000 > $cp) {
            $cp = 0xFFFD;
        }

        // https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.6.4/ext/standard/html.c#L471
        // php_utf32_utf8(unsigned char *buf, unsigned k)

        if ($cp < 0x80) {
            return chr($cp);
        } else if ($cp < 0xA0) {
            return chr(0xC0 | $cp >> 6).chr(0x80 | $cp & 0x3F);
        }

        return html_entity_decode('&#'.$cp.';');
    }, $str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work with supplementary character, such as ``

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that works for my usecase: decoding unicode escape sequences in a string. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a sledgehammer approach to replacing raw UNICODE with HTML. I haven't seen any other place to put this solution, but I assume others have had this problem.

Apply this str_replace function  to the **RAW JSON**, before doing anything
else.

```
function unicode2html($str){
    $i=65535;
    while($i>0){
        $hex=dechex($i);
        $str=str_replace("\u$hex","&#$i;",$str);
        $i--;
     }
     return $str;
}
```

This won't take as long as you think, and this will replace ANY unicode with HTML.

Of course this can be reduced if you know the unicode types that are being returned in the JSON.

For example my code was getting lots of arrows and dingbat unicode. 
These are between 8448 an 11263. So my production code looks like:

```
$i=11263;
while($i>08448){
    ...etc...
```

You can look up the blocks of Unicode by type here: 
http://unicode-table.com/en/
If you know you're translating Arabic or Telegu or whatever, you can just replace those codes, not all 65,000.

You could apply this same sledgehammer to simple encoding:

```
 $str=str_replace("\u$hex",chr($i),$str);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a solution:
http://www.welefen.com/php-unicode-to-utf8.html

```
function entity2utf8onechar($unicode_c){
    $unicode_c_val = intval($unicode_c);
    $f=0x80; // 10000000
    $str = "";
    // U-00000000 - U-0000007F:   0xxxxxxx
    if($unicode_c_val <= 0x7F){         $str = chr($unicode_c_val);     }     //U-00000080 - U-000007FF:  110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
    else if($unicode_c_val >= 0x80 && $unicode_c_val <= 0x7FF){         $h=0xC0; // 11000000
        $c1 = $unicode_c_val >> 6 | $h;
        $c2 = ($unicode_c_val & 0x3F) | $f;
        $str = chr($c1).chr($c2);
    } else if($unicode_c_val >= 0x800 && $unicode_c_val <= 0xFFFF){         $h=0xE0; // 11100000
        $c1 = $unicode_c_val >> 12 | $h;
        $c2 = (($unicode_c_val & 0xFC0) >> 6) | $f;
        $c3 = ($unicode_c_val & 0x3F) | $f;
        $str=chr($c1).chr($c2).chr($c3);
    }
    //U-00010000 - U-001FFFFF:  11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
    else if($unicode_c_val >= 0x10000 && $unicode_c_val <= 0x1FFFFF){         $h=0xF0; // 11110000
        $c1 = $unicode_c_val >> 18 | $h;
        $c2 = (($unicode_c_val & 0x3F000) >>12) | $f;
        $c3 = (($unicode_c_val & 0xFC0) >>6) | $f;
        $c4 = ($unicode_c_val & 0x3F) | $f;
        $str = chr($c1).chr($c2).chr($c3).chr($c4);
    }
    //U-00200000 - U-03FFFFFF:  111110xx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
    else if($unicode_c_val >= 0x200000 && $unicode_c_val <= 0x3FFFFFF){         $h=0xF8; // 11111000
        $c1 = $unicode_c_val >> 24 | $h;
        $c2 = (($unicode_c_val & 0xFC0000)>>18) | $f;
        $c3 = (($unicode_c_val & 0x3F000) >>12) | $f;
        $c4 = (($unicode_c_val & 0xFC0) >>6) | $f;
        $c5 = ($unicode_c_val & 0x3F) | $f;
        $str = chr($c1).chr($c2).chr($c3).chr($c4).chr($c5);
    }
    //U-04000000 - U-7FFFFFFF:  1111110x 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
    else if($unicode_c_val >= 0x4000000 && $unicode_c_val <= 0x7FFFFFFF){         $h=0xFC; // 11111100
        $c1 = $unicode_c_val >> 30 | $h;
        $c2 = (($unicode_c_val & 0x3F000000)>>24) | $f;
        $c3 = (($unicode_c_val & 0xFC0000)>>18) | $f;
        $c4 = (($unicode_c_val & 0x3F000) >>12) | $f;
        $c5 = (($unicode_c_val & 0xFC0) >>6) | $f;
        $c6 = ($unicode_c_val & 0x3F) | $f;
        $str = chr($c1).chr($c2).chr($c3).chr($c4).chr($c5).chr($c6);
    }
    return $str;
}
function entities2utf8($unicode_c){
    $unicode_c = preg_replace("/\&\#([\da-f]{5})\;/es", "entity2utf8onechar('\\1')", $unicode_c);
    return $unicode_c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fix json values,
 it's add \ before u{xxx} to all +" "

```
  $item = preg_replace_callback('/"(.+?)":"(u.+?)",/', function ($matches) {
        $matches[2] = preg_replace('/(u)/', '\u', $matches[2]);
            $matches[2] = preg_replace('/(")/', '&quot;', $matches[2]); 
            $matches[2] = json_decode('"' . $matches[2] . '"'); 
            return '"' . $matches[1] . '":"' . $matches[2] . '",';
        }, $item);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple and beautiful solution.

If we want to decode Unicode escape sequences like `"\u00ed"` to `"í"` we may use simple function `json_decode`:

```php
$a="\u00ed";
echo json_decode("\"$a\"");
# output: í
```

---

It works because `json_encode` encodes all non utf-8 symbols to `\u****` sequence:

```php
echo json_encode("í");
# output: "\u00ed"
```

---

This is a little continuation of the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/7981441/5599052.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7981441/285587