# How to transfer `\u0627` into utf-8(php)

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like “\u00ed” to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-char)

```
$str = '\u0627\u0644\u0631\u0626\u064a\u0633';
```

How to transfer it into utf-8? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$str = '\u0627\u0644\u0631\u0626\u064a\u0633';
$converted = preg_replace('/\\\u([0-9a-z]{4})/i', '&#x$1;', $str);
echo $converted;  // displays الرئيس
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '"\u0627\u0644\u0631\u0626\u064a\u0633"';

echo json_decode($str);
```