# php chr with unicode values

Tags: php, unicode

Can I use unicode value of a character (for example `U+0021` for `!`) in php? and convert it to original character in printing (with `chr()` or other functions)?

Comment: exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}
function unicode_chr ($chr) {
    $x = explode("+", $chr);
    $str = "\u".end($x);
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $str);
}

var_dump(unicode_chr("U+0021")); // string(1) "!"
```

Adapted from: [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-char/2934602#2934602)