# Displaying unicode symbol by outputting unicode with PHP function

Tags: php, html, unicode

I'm trying to output the unicode for a character as a the return type for my PHP function, but when I call the function in practice it just outputs the code without the "0x" rather than a symbol. However, if I explicitly state the unicode in my HTML, it outputs the symbol fine. Below is a simplified version of my code. Why is this happening?

In a PHP file displaying a table:

```
<td><?php echo verifyMatch($a,$b) ?></td>
```

In my function in another file:

```
function verifyMatch($_a,$_b){
  $_output = null;
  if (checkCondition()){
    $_output = 0x2714;
    // unicode for tick
  } else {
    $_output = 0x2718;
    // unicode for cross
  }
  return $_output;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as PHP is concerned, your values `0x2714` and `0x2718` are simply hexadecimal numbers and they are stored as just `2714` and `2718`, respectively. In actuality, PHP should be converting them to their decimal values instead. When outputted into HTML, they are being outputted as just that - numbers.

If you want to output them in HTML and have the actual symbols appear, try pre-pending them with `&#x` and appending them with a `;`:

```
<td><?php echo '&#x' . verifyMatch($a, $b) . ';'; ?></td>
```

If they are being converted to their decimal values, you can prepend them with just `&#` instead of `&#x`. The added `x` is for the hex-values.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [php chr with unicode values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059706/php-chr-with-unicode-values)

```
function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}
function unicode_chr ($chr) {
    $str = "\u".end(explode("+", $chr));
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $str);
}

function verifyMatch($_a,$_b){
    $_output = null;
    if (checkCondition()){
       $_output = unicode_chr("U+2714");   // unicode for tick
    }
    else {
        $_output = unicode_chr("U+2718");   // unicode for cross
    }
    return $_output;
}
```