# How to convert unicode to text in php

Tags: php, decode, encode

Unicode:

```
\u0000T\u0000h\u0000i\u0000s\u0000 \u0000i\u0000s\u0000 \u0000a\u0000 \u0000t\u0000e\u0000s\u0000t\u0000\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd
```

Text:

```
This is a testííí
```

I am receiving this unicode in post request. How to convert above unicode to text. I want to store decoded text in database & database only accept `utf-8` formatting.

This is what I have tried & what I got :

`json_decode()` => `This is a test���`

`utf8_encode()`  => `\u0000T\u0000h\u0000i\u0000s\u0000 \u0000i\u0000s\u0000 \u0000a\u0000 \u0000t\u0000e\u0000s\u0000t\u0000\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd`

`mb_convert_encoding()` => `屵〰〰呜田〰と屵〰〰楜田〰び屵〰〰⁜田〰ど屵〰〰獜田〰〠屵〰〰慜田〰〠屵〰〰瑜田〰づ屵〰〰獜田〰ぴ屵〰〰屵晦晤屵晦晤屵晦晤`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP and accent characters (Ba\u015f\u00e7\u0131l)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306934/php-and-accent-characters-ba-u015f-u00e7-u0131l)

Comment: @Deadooshka I want to store that text in database & database accept only `utf-8`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059706/php-chr-with-unicode-values