# Pretty-Printing JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, pretty-print

I'm building a PHP script that feeds JSON data to another script. My script builds data into a large associative array, and then outputs the data using `json_encode`. Here is an example script:

```
$data = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'catnip');
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
echo json_encode($data);
```

The above code yields the following output:

```
{"a":"apple","b":"banana","c":"catnip"}
```

This is great if you have a small amount of data, but I'd prefer something along these lines:

```
{
    "a": "apple",
    "b": "banana",
    "c": "catnip"
}
```

Is there a way to do this in PHP without an ugly hack? It seems like someone at [Facebook](https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552) figured it out.

Comment: For PHP before 5.4, you can use the fallback in [upgradephp](http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/) as `up_json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: use of **header('Content-Type: application/json');**  makes browser pretty print

Comment: As of Juy 2018, just by sending the `Content-Type: application/json` header Firefox will show the result using its own internal JSON parser, while Chrome shows the plain text. +1 Firefox!

Comment: Are you outputting your json data? Is this for debug purpose? I usually use <pre>print_all(arr)</pre> when debugging on the browser side you can do JSON.parse if needed :-)

Answer (score 1499, accepted):

PHP 5.4 offers the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option for use with the `json_encode()` call.

https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php
...
$json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best way to do it now. I didn't have php 5.4 back when I asked this question though...

Comment: 5.5.3 here, just seems to add a bit of spacing between the characters, not any actual indenting.

Comment: JSON isn't supposed to contain HTML line breaks, whereas newline characters are valid in JSON.  If you want to display JSON on a web page then do a string replacement on the newline characters yourself or else put the JSON in a <pre>...</pre> element.  See http://www.json.org/ for the syntax reference.

Comment: One thing about this is you need the data as an array. I find @Kendall's answer is useful if you're starting out with a json string that needs to be formatted.

Comment: @quickshiftin That's what the `json_decode` function is for.  There's really no need to rewrite functionality that's built into the language.

Comment: Not really, since you'd need to decode, then encode just to get pretty printing, which is a waste of CPU... That's why @Kendall's answer is useful when you're starting out with a string.

Comment: Don't forget to set response `Content-Type` to `application/json` if you want browser to display pretty-printed JSON nicely.

Comment: @countfloortiles it won't work directly you need to enclose your output in `<pre>` tag
like
`<?php
...
$json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "<pre>".$json_string."<pre>";`

Comment: can i get JSON_PRETTY_PRINT with 2 space instead if 4 space?

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo: Looks like you'll need to process the string after pretty printing in order to change the whitespace: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#118334

Comment: That's a really cool feature! Not a big reason to use PHP, but this makes me eager to use PHP more!

Comment: You can also leave Unicode unescaped, like this: `json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT |  JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Answer (score 201):

This function will take JSON string and indent it very readable. It also should be convergent,

```
prettyPrint( $json ) === prettyPrint( prettyPrint( $json ) )
```

Input

```
{"key1":[1,2,3],"key2":"value"}
```

Output

```
{
    "key1": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "key2": "value"
}
```

Code

```
function prettyPrint( $json )
{
    $result = '';
    $level = 0;
    $in_quotes = false;
    $in_escape = false;
    $ends_line_level = NULL;
    $json_length = strlen( $json );

    for( $i = 0; $i < $json_length; $i++ ) {
        $char = $json[$i];
        $new_line_level = NULL;
        $post = "";
        if( $ends_line_level !== NULL ) {
            $new_line_level = $ends_line_level;
            $ends_line_level = NULL;
        }
        if ( $in_escape ) {
            $in_escape = false;
        } else if( $char === '"' ) {
            $in_quotes = !$in_quotes;
        } else if( ! $in_quotes ) {
            switch( $char ) {
                case '}': case ']':
                    $level--;
                    $ends_line_level = NULL;
                    $new_line_level = $level;
                    break;

                case '{': case '[':
                    $level++;
                case ',':
                    $ends_line_level = $level;
                    break;

                case ':':
                    $post = " ";
                    break;

                case " ": case "\t": case "\n": case "\r":
                    $char = "";
                    $ends_line_level = $new_line_level;
                    $new_line_level = NULL;
                    break;
            }
        } else if ( $char === '\\' ) {
            $in_escape = true;
        }
        if( $new_line_level !== NULL ) {
            $result .= "\n".str_repeat( "\t", $new_line_level );
        }
        $result .= $char.$post;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 130):

Many users suggested that you use

```
echo json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Which is absolutely right. But it's not enough, the browser needs to understand the type of data, you can specify the header just before echo-ing the data back to the user.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

This will result in a well formatted output.

Or, if you like extensions you can use JSONView for Chrome.

Comment: **Only set the header** and Firefox will show it perfectly using its own internal JSON debugging parser, no need to touch the JSON contents at all! Thank you!!

Comment: Using a chromium browser with a JSON prettifier extension, my JSON output was not being formatted. **Just setting the header** made the extension work.

Answer (score 81):

I realize this question is asking about how to encode an associative array to a pretty-formatted JSON string, so this doesn't directly answer the question, but if you have a string that is already in JSON format, you can make it pretty simply by decoding and re-encoding it (requires PHP >= 5.4):

```
$json = json_encode(json_decode($json), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

### Example:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json_ugly = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$json_pretty = json_encode(json_decode($json_ugly), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json_pretty;
```

This outputs:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4,
    "e": 5
}
```

Comment: thanks, it only works if i add this at the top of php block...  header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: @DeyaEldeen If you don't use that header, PHP will tell the browser that it is sending HTML, so you would have to view the page source to see the formatted JSON string. I assumed that was understood, but I guess not. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: And anyone tailing/reviewing a log/file in the unix/linux shell, this is the solution here!  Good looking out, @Mike, makes it easy to read!.

Comment: @fusion27 I'm not really sure what log files you're referring to. I've never heard of any programs that log anything in JSON.

Comment: @Mike, it's a quick-n-dirty PHP I whipped up appending the request body (which is a serialized JSON string) POSTed to my PHP in to a textfile, I then tail it in the unix shell so I can watch live POSTs.  I'm using your trick to format that JSON making the text file much more usable.

Comment: Nice I didn't realize the header was necessary

Answer (score 41):

Gluing several answers together fit my need for **existing json:**

```
Code:
echo "<pre>"; 
echo json_encode(json_decode($json_response), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
echo "</pre>";

Output:
{
    "data": {
        "token_type": "bearer",
        "expires_in": 3628799,
        "scopes": "full_access",
        "created_at": 1540504324
    },
    "errors": [],
    "pagination": {},
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 3628799,
    "scopes": "full_access",
    "created_at": 1540504324
}
```

Comment: Here's a little wrapper function to do this: `function json_print($json) { return '<pre>' . json_encode(json_decode($json), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>'; }`

Answer (score 40):

I had the same issue.

Anyway I just used the json formatting code here:

http://recursive-design.com/blog/2008/03/11/format-json-with-php/

Works well for what I needed it for.

And a more maintained version: https://github.com/GerHobbelt/nicejson-php

Comment: I tried https://github.com/GerHobbelt/nicejson-php and it works great in PHP 5.3.

Comment: If you are on PHP7.0 (and above) and still need to pretty-print JSON with custom indentation, https://localheinz.com/blog/2018/01/04/pretty-printing-json-with-custom-indent/ should help.

Answer (score 28):

I have used this:

```
echo "<pre>".json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)."</pre>";
```

Or use php headers as below:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 12):

much easier to remind: enter **128**

**128** is a synonyme for the constant "JSON_PRETTY_PRINT"

( [PHP Docs Site](https://www.php.net/manual/de/json.constants.php#115783))

```
json_encode($json,128);
//similar to
json_encode($json,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

Comment: Please share more details. To me, this looks like a duplicate of the answer that awhie29urh2 provided nine years ago. Is there something new you want to highlight?

Comment: Enums are not there just for the sake of it. I personally would not recommend a enum value with a number. This will of course work, but the code is less understandable.

Comment: but the name is hard to remember, you always have to go to PHP Docs 

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/de/json.constants.php#115783

Comment: If verbosity is a problem and you're calling this often, I'd prefer to write a simple wrapper utility function, like `json_pretty_encode()` than use a magic number.

Answer (score 11):

I took the code from Composer : https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php and nicejson : https://github.com/GerHobbelt/nicejson-php/blob/master/nicejson.php
Composer code is good because it updates fluently from 5.3 to 5.4 but it only encodes object whereas nicejson takes json strings, so i merged them. The code can be used to format json string and/or encode objects, i'm currently using it in a Drupal module.

```
if (!defined('JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES'))
    define('JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES', 64);
if (!defined('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT'))
    define('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT', 128);
if (!defined('JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE'))
    define('JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE', 256);

function _json_encode($data, $options = 448)
{
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4', '>='))
    {
        return json_encode($data, $options);
    }

    return _json_format(json_encode($data), $options);
}

function _pretty_print_json($json)
{
    return _json_format($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}

function _json_format($json, $options = 448)
{
    $prettyPrint = (bool) ($options & JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $unescapeUnicode = (bool) ($options & JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    $unescapeSlashes = (bool) ($options & JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

    if (!$prettyPrint && !$unescapeUnicode && !$unescapeSlashes)
    {
        return $json;
    }

    $result = '';
    $pos = 0;
    $strLen = strlen($json);
    $indentStr = ' ';
    $newLine = "\n";
    $outOfQuotes = true;
    $buffer = '';
    $noescape = true;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $strLen; $i++)
    {
        // Grab the next character in the string
        $char = substr($json, $i, 1);

        // Are we inside a quoted string?
        if ('"' === $char && $noescape)
        {
            $outOfQuotes = !$outOfQuotes;
        }

        if (!$outOfQuotes)
        {
            $buffer .= $char;
            $noescape = '\\' === $char ? !$noescape : true;
            continue;
        }
        elseif ('' !== $buffer)
        {
            if ($unescapeSlashes)
            {
                $buffer = str_replace('\\/', '/', $buffer);
            }

            if ($unescapeUnicode && function_exists('mb_convert_encoding'))
            {
                // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha
                $buffer = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i',
                    function ($match)
                    {
                        return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
                    }, $buffer);
            } 

            $result .= $buffer . $char;
            $buffer = '';
            continue;
        }
        elseif(false !== strpos(" \t\r\n", $char))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (':' === $char)
        {
            // Add a space after the : character
            $char .= ' ';
        }
        elseif (('}' === $char || ']' === $char))
        {
            $pos--;
            $prevChar = substr($json, $i - 1, 1);

            if ('{' !== $prevChar && '[' !== $prevChar)
            {
                // If this character is the end of an element,
                // output a new line and indent the next line
                $result .= $newLine;
                for ($j = 0; $j < $pos; $j++)
                {
                    $result .= $indentStr;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Collapse empty {} and []
                $result = rtrim($result) . "\n\n" . $indentStr;
            }
        }

        $result .= $char;

        // If the last character was the beginning of an element,
        // output a new line and indent the next line
        if (',' === $char || '{' === $char || '[' === $char)
        {
            $result .= $newLine;

            if ('{' === $char || '[' === $char)
            {
                $pos++;
            }

            for ($j = 0; $j < $pos; $j++)
            {
                $result .= $indentStr;
            }
        }
    }
    // If buffer not empty after formating we have an unclosed quote
    if (strlen($buffer) > 0)
    {
        //json is incorrectly formatted
        $result = false;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: This is how it's done! Own implementation runs only if native is not available. If you are sure your code will only run in PHP 5.4 or above you may rest on JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

Comment: This solution gives me error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION) on line function ($match)

Comment: Composer took it from https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2008/03/11/format-json-with-php/, which is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/6054389/1172545.

Answer (score 11):

best way to format JSON data is like this!

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Replace $response with your Data which is required to be converted to JSON

Comment: What makes this the best way?

Answer (score 10):

Have color full output: Tiny Solution

Code:

```
$s = '{"access": {"token": {"issued_at": "2008-08-16T14:10:31.309353", "expires": "2008-08-17T14:10:31Z", "id": "MIICQgYJKoZIhvcIegeyJpc3N1ZWRfYXQiOiAi"}, "serviceCatalog": [], "user": {"username": "ajay", "roles_links": [], "id": "16452ca89", "roles": [], "name": "ajay"}}}';

$crl = 0;
$ss = false;
echo "<pre>";
for($c=0; $c<strlen($s); $c++)
{
    if ( $s[$c] == '}' || $s[$c] == ']' )
    {
        $crl--;
        echo "\n";
        echo str_repeat(' ', ($crl*2));
    }
    if ( $s[$c] == '"' && ($s[$c-1] == ',' || $s[$c-2] == ',') )
    {
        echo "\n";
        echo str_repeat(' ', ($crl*2));
    }
    if ( $s[$c] == '"' && !$ss )
    {
        if ( $s[$c-1] == ':' || $s[$c-2] == ':' )
            echo '<span style="color:#0000ff;">';
        else
            echo '<span style="color:#ff0000;">';
    }
    echo $s[$c];
    if ( $s[$c] == '"' && $ss )
        echo '</span>';
    if ( $s[$c] == '"' )
          $ss = !$ss;
    if ( $s[$c] == '{' || $s[$c] == '[' )
    {
        $crl++;
        echo "\n";
        echo str_repeat(' ', ($crl*2));
    }
}
echo $s[$c];
```

Comment: this was very helpful, even though it had a few errors in it. I fixed them and now it works like a charm, and the function is not that big at all! thanks Ajay

Comment: just to comment on the fixes if anyone wants to use this... add a validation check $c > 1 in the second and and third if condition, and the last echo wrap it into an is_array($s) if. that should cover it and you shouldn't get any Uninitialized string offset error.

Answer (score 9):

If you are on firefox install [JSONovich](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/jsonovich/). Not really a PHP solution I know, but it does the trick for development purposes/debugging.

Comment: I think this is the proper solution for when dev'ing an api. It gives the best of both worlds, easy debugging since you can read everything and you are not altering the backends behaviour, including its performance.

Comment: Agreed, it's nicely formatted with colours and collapsible too. Much nicer than you could hope to achieve with a bit of PHP

Answer (score 8):

Simple way for php>5.4: like in Facebook graph

```html
$Data = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'catnip');
$json= json_encode($Data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print_r($json);
```

Result in browser

```
{
    "a": "apple",
    "b": "banana",
    "c": "catnip"
}
```

Comment: @Madbreaks, it's prints well in php file, don't need to write in json file, same as like facebook.

Answer (score 8):

Use `<pre>` in combination with `json_encode()` and the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option:

```
<pre>
    <?php
    echo json_encode($dataArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have existing JSON (`$ugly_json`)

```
echo nl2br(str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', (json_encode(json_decode($ugly_json), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 6):

You can modify Kendall Hopkins' answer a little in the switch statement to get a pretty clean looking and nicely indented printout by passing a json string into the following:

```
function prettyPrint( $json ){

$result = '';
$level = 0;
$in_quotes = false;
$in_escape = false;
$ends_line_level = NULL;
$json_length = strlen( $json );

for( $i = 0; $i < $json_length; $i++ ) {
    $char = $json[$i];
    $new_line_level = NULL;
    $post = "";
    if( $ends_line_level !== NULL ) {
        $new_line_level = $ends_line_level;
        $ends_line_level = NULL;
    }
    if ( $in_escape ) {
        $in_escape = false;
    } else if( $char === '"' ) {
        $in_quotes = !$in_quotes;
    } else if( ! $in_quotes ) {
        switch( $char ) {
            case '}': case ']':
                $level--;
                $ends_line_level = NULL;
                $new_line_level = $level;
                $char.="<br>";
                for($index=0;$index<$level-1;$index++){$char.="-----";}
                break;

            case '{': case '[':
                $level++;
                $char.="<br>";
                for($index=0;$index<$level;$index++){$char.="-----";}
                break;
            case ',':
                $ends_line_level = $level;
                $char.="<br>";
                for($index=0;$index<$level;$index++){$char.="-----";}
                break;

            case ':':
                $post = " ";
                break;

            case "\t": case "\n": case "\r":
                $char = "";
                $ends_line_level = $new_line_level;
                $new_line_level = NULL;
                break;
        }
    } else if ( $char === '\\' ) {
        $in_escape = true;
    }
    if( $new_line_level !== NULL ) {
        $result .= "\n".str_repeat( "\t", $new_line_level );
    }
    $result .= $char.$post;
}

echo "RESULTS ARE: <br><br>$result";
return $result;
```

}

Now just run the function prettyPrint( $your_json_string ); inline in your php and enjoy the printout. If you're a minimalist and don't like brackets for some reason, you can get rid of those easily by replacing the `$char.="<br>";` with `$char="<br>";` in the top three switch cases on $char. Here's what you get for a google maps API call for the city of Calgary

```
RESULTS ARE: 

{
- - - "results" : [
- - -- - - {
- - -- - -- - - "address_components" : [
- - -- - -- - -- - - {
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "long_name" : "Calgary"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "short_name" : "Calgary"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "types" : [
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "locality"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "political" ]
- - -- - -- - -- - - }
- - -- - -- - -
- - -- - -- - -- - - {
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "long_name" : "Division No. 6"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "short_name" : "Division No. 6"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "types" : [
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "administrative_area_level_2"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "political" ]
- - -- - -- - -- - - }
- - -- - -- - -
- - -- - -- - -- - - {
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "long_name" : "Alberta"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "short_name" : "AB"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "types" : [
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "administrative_area_level_1"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "political" ]
- - -- - -- - -- - - }
- - -- - -- - -
- - -- - -- - -- - - {
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "long_name" : "Canada"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "short_name" : "CA"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "types" : [
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "country"
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "political" ]
- - -- - -- - -- - - }
- - -- - -- - - ]
- - -- - -
- - -- - -- - - "formatted_address" : "Calgary, AB, Canada"
- - -- - -- - - "geometry" : {
- - -- - -- - -- - - "bounds" : {
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "northeast" : {
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "lat" : 51.18383
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "lng" : -113.8769511 }
- - -- - -- - -- - -
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "southwest" : {
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "lat" : 50.84240399999999
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "lng" : -114.27136 }
- - -- - -- - -- - - }
- - -- - -- - -
- - -- - -- - -- - - "location" : {
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "lat" : 51.0486151
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "lng" : -114.0708459 }
- - -- - -- - -
- - -- - -- - -- - - "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE"
- - -- - -- - -- - - "viewport" : {
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "northeast" : {
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "lat" : 51.18383
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "lng" : -113.8769511 }
- - -- - -- - -- - -
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "southwest" : {
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "lat" : 50.84240399999999
- - -- - -- - -- - -- - -- - - "lng" : -114.27136 }
- - -- - -- - -- - - }
- - -- - -- - - }
- - -- - -
- - -- - -- - - "place_id" : "ChIJ1T-EnwNwcVMROrZStrE7bSY"
- - -- - -- - - "types" : [
- - -- - -- - -- - - "locality"
- - -- - -- - -- - - "political" ]
- - -- - - }
- - - ]

- - - "status" : "OK" }
```

Comment: This is really nice thanks. One thing I think to add slight improvement is use a var for: $indent = "-----", then use that (instead of "-----" in different places in the code)

Answer (score 6):

For those running PHP version 5.3 or before, you may try below:

```
$pretty_json = "<pre>".print_r(json_decode($json), true)."</pre>";

echo $pretty_json;
```

Answer (score 6):

I usually use one of these one-liners.

If you already have an JSON string, you can simply use a combination of `echo()` and `print_r()`.
Don't forget to pass the second parameter of `print_r()` to `true` so that it returns the value rather than printing it:

```
echo('<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>');
```

or you can use `die()` which is handy for debugging:

```
die('<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>');
```

If you have an array, you need to convert it to a JSON string before.
Be sure to set the second parameter of `json_encode()` with the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag so your JSON will be correctly rendered:

```
echo('<pre>' . print_r(json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), true) . '</pre>');
```

or for debugging:

```
die('<pre>' . print_r(json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), true) . '</pre>');
```

Comment: Apt for rendering onto a webpage.

Answer (score 5):

This solution makes 'really pretty' JSON.  Not exactly what the OP was asking for, but it lets you visualise the JSON better.

```
/**
 * takes an object parameter and returns the pretty json format.
 * this is a space saving version that uses 2 spaces instead of the regular 4
 *
 * @param $in
 *
 * @return string
 */
function pretty_json ($in): string
{
  return preg_replace_callback('/^ +/m',
    function (array $matches): string
    {
      return str_repeat(' ', strlen($matches[0]) / 2);
    }, json_encode($in, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_HEX_APOS)
  );
}

/**
 * takes a JSON string an adds colours to the keys/values
 * if the string is not JSON then it is returned unaltered.
 *
 * @param string $in
 *
 * @return string
 */

function markup_json (string $in): string
{
  $string  = 'green';
  $number  = 'darkorange';
  $null    = 'magenta';
  $key     = 'red';
  $pattern = '/("(\\\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\\\[^u]|[^\\\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/';
  return preg_replace_callback($pattern,
      function (array $matches) use ($string, $number, $null, $key): string
      {
        $match  = $matches[0];
        $colour = $number;
        if (preg_match('/^"/', $match))
        {
          $colour = preg_match('/:$/', $match)
            ? $key
            : $string;
        }
        elseif ($match === 'null')
        {
          $colour = $null;
        }
        return "<span style='color:{$colour}'>{$match}</span>";
      }, str_replace(['<', '>', '&'], ['&lt;', '&gt;', '&amp;'], $in)
   ) ?? $in;
}

public function test_pretty_json_object ()
{
  $ob       = new \stdClass();
  $ob->test = 'unit-tester';
  $json     = pretty_json($ob);
  $expected = <<<JSON
{
  "test": "unit-tester"
}
JSON;
  $this->assertEquals($expected, $json);
}

public function test_pretty_json_str ()
{
  $ob   = 'unit-tester';
  $json = pretty_json($ob);
  $this->assertEquals("\"$ob\"", $json);
}

public function test_markup_json ()
{
  $json = <<<JSON
[{"name":"abc","id":123,"warnings":[],"errors":null},{"name":"abc"}]
JSON;
  $expected = <<<STR
[
  {
    <span style='color:red'>"name":</span> <span style='color:green'>"abc"</span>,
    <span style='color:red'>"id":</span> <span style='color:darkorange'>123</span>,
    <span style='color:red'>"warnings":</span> [],
    <span style='color:red'>"errors":</span> <span style='color:magenta'>null</span>
  },
  {
    <span style='color:red'>"name":</span> <span style='color:green'>"abc"</span>
  }
]
STR;

  $output = markup_json(pretty_json(json_decode($json)));
  $this->assertEquals($expected,$output);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

If you used only `$json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`, you will get in the browser something like this (using the [Facebook link](https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552) from the question :) ):
[image]

**but** if you used a chrome Extension like [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) (even without the PHP option above), then you get a more **pretty readable debuggable solution** where you can even Fold/Collapse each single JSON object easily like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like below.

```
$array = array(
   "a" => "apple",
   "b" => "banana",
   "c" => "catnip"
);

foreach ($array as $a_key => $a_val) {
   $json .= "\"{$a_key}\" : \"{$a_val}\",\n";
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo "{\n"  .rtrim($json, ",\n") . "\n}";
```

Above would output kind of like Facebook.

```
{
"a" : "apple",
"b" : "banana",
"c" : "catnip"
}
```

Comment: What if `a_val` is an array or an object?

Comment: I answered an example using the Json in the question, I will update my answer soon.

Answer (score 3):

Classic case for a recursive solution.  Here's mine:

```
class JsonFormatter {
    public static function prettyPrint(&$j, $indentor = "\t", $indent = "") {
        $inString = $escaped = false;
        $result = $indent;

        if(is_string($j)) {
            $bak = $j;
            $j = str_split(trim($j, '"'));
        }

        while(count($j)) {
            $c = array_shift($j);
            if(false !== strpos("{[,]}", $c)) {
                if($inString) {
                    $result .= $c;
                } else if($c == '{' || $c == '[') {
                    $result .= $c."\n";
                    $result .= self::prettyPrint($j, $indentor, $indentor.$indent);
                    $result .= $indent.array_shift($j);
                } else if($c == '}' || $c == ']') {
                    array_unshift($j, $c);
                    $result .= "\n";
                    return $result;
                } else {
                    $result .= $c."\n".$indent;
                } 
            } else {
                $result .= $c;
                $c == '"' && !$escaped && $inString = !$inString;
                $escaped = $c == '\\' ? !$escaped : false;
            }
        }

        $j = $bak;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
php > require 'JsonFormatter.php';
php > $a = array('foo' => 1, 'bar' => 'This "is" bar', 'baz' => array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => '"3"'));
php > print_r($a);
Array
(
    [foo] => 1
    [bar] => This "is" bar
    [baz] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => "3"
        )

)
php > echo JsonFormatter::prettyPrint(json_encode($a));
{
    "foo":1,
    "bar":"This \"is\" bar",
    "baz":{
        "a":1,
        "b":2,
        "c":"\"3\""
    }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

print_r pretty print for PHP

[Example PHP](http://shellykaohsiung.blogspot.tw/2016/07/php-printr-pretty-print-for-php.html)

```
function print_nice($elem,$max_level=10,$print_nice_stack=array()){
    if(is_array($elem) || is_object($elem)){
        if(in_array($elem,$print_nice_stack,true)){
            echo "<font color=red>RECURSION</font>";
            return;
        }
        $print_nice_stack[]=&$elem;
        if($max_level<1){
            echo "<font color=red>nivel maximo alcanzado</font>";
            return;
        }
        $max_level--;
        echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3 width=100%>";
        if(is_array($elem)){
            echo '<tr><td colspan=2 style="background-color:#333333;"><strong><font color=white>ARRAY</font></strong></td></tr>';
        }else{
            echo '<tr><td colspan=2 style="background-color:#333333;"><strong>';
            echo '<font color=white>OBJECT Type: '.get_class($elem).'</font></strong></td></tr>';
        }
        $color=0;
        foreach($elem as $k => $v){
            if($max_level%2){
                $rgb=($color++%2)?"#888888":"#BBBBBB";
            }else{
                $rgb=($color++%2)?"#8888BB":"#BBBBFF";
            }
            echo '<tr><td valign="top" style="width:40px;background-color:'.$rgb.';">';
            echo '<strong>'.$k."</strong></td><td>";
            print_nice($v,$max_level,$print_nice_stack);
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        return;
    }
    if($elem === null){
        echo "<font color=green>NULL</font>";
    }elseif($elem === 0){
        echo "0";
    }elseif($elem === true){
        echo "<font color=green>TRUE</font>";
    }elseif($elem === false){
        echo "<font color=green>FALSE</font>";
    }elseif($elem === ""){
        echo "<font color=green>EMPTY STRING</font>";
    }else{
        echo str_replace("\n","<strong><font color=red>*</font></strong><br>\n",$elem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - `json_encode($rows,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` returns prettified data with newline characters. This is helpful for command line input, but as you've discovered doesn't look as pretty within the browser. The browser will accept the newlines as the source (and thus, viewing the page source will indeed show the pretty JSON), but they aren't used to format the output in browsers. Browsers require HTML.

2 - use this fuction [github](https://gist.github.com/drazisil/eda9065698dd0beedede)

```
<?php
    /**
     * Formats a JSON string for pretty printing
     *
     * @param string $json The JSON to make pretty
     * @param bool $html Insert nonbreaking spaces and <br />s for tabs and linebreaks
     * @return string The prettified output
     * @author Jay Roberts
     */
    function _format_json($json, $html = false) {
        $tabcount = 0;
        $result = '';
        $inquote = false;
        $ignorenext = false;
        if ($html) {
            $tab = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            $newline = "<br/>";
        } else {
            $tab = "\t";
            $newline = "\n";
        }
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($json); $i++) {
            $char = $json[$i];
            if ($ignorenext) {
                $result .= $char;
                $ignorenext = false;
            } else {
                switch($char) {
                    case '[':
                    case '{':
                        $tabcount++;
                        $result .= $char . $newline . str_repeat($tab, $tabcount);
                        break;
                    case ']':
                    case '}':
                        $tabcount--;
                        $result = trim($result) . $newline . str_repeat($tab, $tabcount) . $char;
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        $result .= $char . $newline . str_repeat($tab, $tabcount);
                        break;
                    case '"':
                        $inquote = !$inquote;
                        $result .= $char;
                        break;
                    case '\\':
                        if ($inquote) $ignorenext = true;
                        $result .= $char;
                        break;
                    default:
                        $result .= $char;
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

here's the function i use myself, the api is just like json_encode, except it has a 3rd argument `exclude_flags` in case you want to exclude some of the default flags (like JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)

```php
function json_encode_pretty($data, int $extra_flags = 0, int $exclude_flags = 0): string
{
    // prettiest flags for: 7.3.9
    $flags = JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | (defined("JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS") ? JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS : 0) | JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION | (defined("JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR") ? JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR : 0);
    $flags = ($flags | $extra_flags) & ~ $exclude_flags;
    return (json_encode($data, $flags));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is what worked for me:

Contents of test.php:

```
<html>
<body>
Testing JSON array output
  <pre>
  <?php
  $data = array('a'=>'apple', 'b'=>'banana', 'c'=>'catnip');
  // encode in json format 
  $data = json_encode($data);

  // json as single line
  echo "</br>Json as single line </br>";
  echo $data;
  // json as an array, formatted nicely
  echo "</br>Json as multiline array </br>";
  print_r(json_decode($data, true));
  ?>
  </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

output:

```
Testing JSON array output


Json as single line 
{"a":"apple","b":"banana","c":"catnip"}
Json as multiline array 
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => catnip
)
```

Also note the use of "pre" tag in html.

Hope that helps someone

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  You're dumping vars, not printing formatted JSON.

Answer (score -6):

If you are working with **MVC**

try doing this in your controller

```
public function getLatestUsers() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $this->model->getLatestUsers(); // this returns json_encode($somedata, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
}
```

then if you call /getLatestUsers you will get a pretty JSON output ;)

Comment: see my comment after the echo where it is being pretty printend

Comment: MVC is a type of framework design, nothing to do with outputting JSON.

Comment: its an answer from 2013 people ;)