# PHP "pretty print" json_encode

Tags: php, json, encode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pretty-Printing JSON with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)

I'm working on a script that creates a JSON file. Right now I'm just using `json_encode` (PHP 5.2.x) to encode an array into JSON output. Then I print the returned value to a file and save it. Problem is that the client wants to be able to open these JSON files for readability, so I'd like to add line breaks in and "pretty print" the JSON output. Any ideas on how to do this? My only other alternative that I can see is to not use `json_encode` at all and just write the file contents manually and add in my own line breaks for each line.

Here's what I get:

```
{"product_name":"prod1","val1":1,"val2":8}
```

Here's what I want:

```
{
  "product_name":"prod1",
  "val1":1,
  "val2":8
}
```

I suppose I could also just replace every comma with a command followed by a \n, and same for the brackets... Thoughts?

Comment: See [this comment in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#80339).

Comment: $jsonArr  = '{"product_name":"prod1","val1":1,"val2":8}'; 
$jsonArr = json_decode($jsonArr);
echo "<pre>";print_R($jsonArr);

Answer (score 355, accepted):

PHP has JSON_PRETTY_PRINT option since 5.4.0 (release date 01-Mar-2012).

This should do the job:

```
$json = json_decode($string);
echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Note: Don't forget to echo "<pre>" before and "</pre>" after, if you're printing it in HTML to preserve formatting ;)

Comment: In PHP <5.4 replace `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` with 128

Comment: @NicCottrell doesn't work when i test it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99ef7015efd0e31a06bd3d0d1130f7b9ace9e7a4

Comment: @drzaus works for me there - I can see each key of JSON on separate line (the PHP version used on that site has even JSON_PRETTY_PRINT defined.

Comment: @beret ahh, I thought sharing it would retain the PHP setting -- change the php version to anything less than 5.4 and it should go back to "unformatted"

Comment: @drzaus Oh I see. I didn't look for the switch of PHP version. Yeah, apparently not only the constant has been added, but mainly the functionality. Makes sense.

Comment: Instead of using "<pre>" tags (which will render your JSON invalid), you ought to use `header("Content-Type: application/json")` and then your browser will render it as plain text rather than markup.

Answer (score 11):

Hmmm `$array = json_decode($json, true);` will make your string an array which is easy to print nicely with `print_r($array, true);`

But if you really want to prettify your json... [Check this out](http://recursive-design.com/blog/2008/03/11/format-json-with-php/)

Comment: @Michael Mior you should see my debugging die `die(print('<pre>'.print_r($var, true).'</pre>'))` it prints almost anything :p

Comment: I usually just view the source and go with `var_dump`, but whatever works :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function to pretty up your json:
[pretty_json](http://snipplr.com/view/60559/prettyjson/)

Comment: Just wondering how `brew install php54` is considered a lot of work. When doing development on a Mac, it's fairly likely you have homebrew installed...