# How to format json file view on html

Tags: html, json

current json view on html page

```
{"result": [{"id": "103300640", "sms_phone": "730276061", "corrected to": 
"27730276061"}, {"id": "103277733", "sms_phone": "716125197", "corrected 
 to": "27716125197"}]}
```

what I want it to be formatted display like

```
{  
   "result":[  
      {  
         "id":"103300640",
         "sms_phone":"730276061",
         "corrected to":"27730276061"
      },
      {  
         "id":"103277733",
         "sms_phone":"716125197",
         "corrected to":"27716125197"
      }]
}
```

JS code:

```
@app.route('/<path:req_path>')
def dir_listing(req_path):
   abs_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, req_path)
   # Check if path is a file and serve
   if os.path.isfile(abs_path):
      return send_file(abs_path, mimetype="application/json")    
return render_template('/index.html')
```

HTML code:

```
<ul>
    {% for file in file_list %}
    <li><a href="{{ file }}" id="list">{{ file }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: So you just want to format json?

Comment: I believe this is already answered by other similar questions. You might wanna take a look at this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862627/json-stringify-output-to-div-in-pretty-print-way).

Comment: It does not help me. I'm having the json file listed on html page and on user click it should open the beautified json format.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this out:

Use `<pre>` tag for showing code itself in `HTML` page and with `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
var data = {"result": [{"id": "103300640", "sms_phone": "730276061", "corrected to": "27730276061"}, {"id": "103277733", "sms_phone": "716125197", "corrected  to": "27716125197"}]}


document.getElementById("beautified").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="beautified"></pre>
```

The `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a re-placer function is specified or optionally including only the specified properties if a re-placer array is specified.

Comment: the json is in the file and code is <ul>
    {% for file in file_list %}
    <li><a href="{{ file }}" >{{ file }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

Comment: I meant how to use the 'pre' tag for a json file similar like teh code example given above.

Comment: you can use it in HTML not in JSON file.

Comment: yes in html file (as per the example) only I am asking. In this question description above, I mentioned HTML code. Could you please modify that and paste it here?

Comment: Nice, simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify`

See example at: https://codepen.io/adrianparr/pen/VeyeVP

Comment: Mine is the json file. How do I use that <pre> tag in this code  - <ul>
    {% for file in file_list %}
    
    <li><a href="{{ file }}" >{{ file }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

Comment: Please provide your code in stackBlitz in order to enable edit

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JS to achieve this.
Please have a look at the below code.
Use the `<pre>` tag to achieve this.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<script>
function myFunction() {
var data = {
    "data": {
        "x": "1",
        "y": "1",
        "url": "http://test.com"
    },
    "event": "start",
    "show": 1,
    "id": 50
}


document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
}

</script>
<pre id="json"></pre>
</body>
<html>
```