# unable to properly print json api in javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html, json, object, stringify

I'm getting a json api back from my javascript request. I able to print the output to console and it looks properly formatted eg

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "John"
}
```

but when I print to html page. it looks like this

```
'{"id": "1", "name": "john"}'
```

here my javascript file

```
$(function() {
    //variables
    var functionName = 'getQuotes';

    function LoadData() {
        $.get("http://localhost/quoteapi/api.php?function="+functionName+"&jsonCallback=?", function(data) {
            // console.log(data);
            jsonstr = data.substring(2, data.length-1)
            console.log(jsonstr);
            var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify(jsonstr,null,6);           
        });
    }

    LoadData();      
});
```

and I want to print to a `<p>` tag with id of "quote"

```
<p id="quote"></p>
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Are you saying when you inject that string in the page it changes the case of "John" to "john"? Maybe share more of what you're expecting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.stringify output to div in pretty print way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862627/json-stringify-output-to-div-in-pretty-print-way)

Answer (score 1):

use a `<pre>` tag instead of a `<p>` tag, or add some CSS to maintain the whitespace formatting you want.

```css
.code {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
Unstyled &lt;p&gt; tag
<p>
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "John"
}
</p>

<hr>
Unstyled &lt;pre&gt; tag
<pre>
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "John"
}
</pre>

<hr>
Styled &lt;p&gt; tag
<p class="code">
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "John"
}
</p>
```

Comment: I though it would be possible to do the formatting from JavaScript so I don't have to create a model html page...

Answer (score 1):

In a different way you can replace each '\n' (newline) with a <br> and a space with &nbsp;.

The snippet:

```js
var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify( { "id": "1", "name": "John" } ,null,6);
document.querySelector('#quote').innerHTML = jsonPretty
     .replace(/\n( *)/g, function (match, p1) {
         return '<br>' + '&nbsp;'.repeat(p1.length);
     });


var x = { "data": { "x": "1", "y": "1", "url": "http://url.com" }, "event": "start", "show": 1, "id": 50 };
document.querySelector('#newquote').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(x, null, 6)
     .replace(/\n( *)/g, function (match, p1) {
         return '<br>' + '&nbsp;'.repeat(p1.length);
     });
```

```html
<p id="quote"></p>
---------------------
<p id="newquote"></p>
```