# How to beautify parsed JSON in ReactJS?

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to create a XML to JSON converter app which accepts a custom .xml file and parse the content in it to JSON object using xml2json-ltx library. I have done the parsing/converting part but the result JSON is a bit ugly.

I just want to beautify the parsed JSON and add the proper indentations in the resulting JSON Object. How can I? Please comment/answer with an example please :)

LtxParser.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import parser from "xml2json-ltx";
const Ltx = () => {
  const [fileState, setFileData] = useState();
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!fileState) {
      const resultObj = parser.toJson(fileState, {
        object: true,
      });
      setJsonData(resultObj);
    }
  }, [fileState]);
  const onFileDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const fileData = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
      setFileData(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(fileData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Ltx
      <input type="file" onChange={onFileDrop} />
      {jsonData && JSON.stringify(jsonData, undefined, 4)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Ltx;
```

Sample.xml

```
<catalog>
<book id="bk101">
<author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
<title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
<genre>Computer</genre>
<price>44.95</price>
<publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
<description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
</book>
<book id="bk102">
<author>Ralls, Kim</author>
<title>Midnight Rain</title>
<genre>Fantasy</genre>
<price>5.95</price>
<publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
<description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
</book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862627/json-stringify-output-to-div-in-pretty-print-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told in the comment and other SO answers, you can use the pre-tag and display the stringified JSON object inside the pre-tag to display line breaks, indentation, etc., as in the parsed data.

Eg :

```
<div>
      Ltx
      <input type="file" onChange={onFileDrop} />
      <pre>
        {jsonData && JSON.stringify(jsonData, undefined, 4)}
      </pre>
</div>
```