# Styling a vaadin Component (Dialog) with CSS file

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I have a Dialog that retrieve informations from an endpoint (String of information) but I have a Problem with style this dialog, because all these informations appear untidily!

For example to be clear, I have this endpoint, that it helps me to retrieve a Data about Mobile, and want to show this Data in a Dialog (BUT the Style should like Screenshot Nr. 1), but my Problem is that the data appears as Preview (Screenshot 2).

[image]

Comment: If I  understand correctly you want to pretty print the JSON, right?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes my friend i want a pretty print.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to put the formatted JSON in a <pre></pre> block https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862627/json-stringify-output-to-div-in-pretty-print-way

Comment: @SimonMartinelli can i use it in css-file??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Html` component with a `pre` tag where you put the formatted JSON:

```
Html pre = new Html("<pre>" + formattedJson + "</pre>");
```

To format the JSON String you can use this:

```
String prettyJson = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                          .writeValueAsString(mapper.readTree(inputJson));
```

Find more examples here: https://roytuts.com/how-to-pretty-print-json-in-java/

Comment: it works thanks but it shows the information in one line !

Comment: Have you formatted the JSON? https://roytuts.com/how-to-pretty-print-json-in-java/

Comment: no because i read the data from an endpoint (not directly from JOSN file) and the Data be able to change.
i mean i want to call the endpoint to show the data..

Comment: That doesn't matter where the JSON string comes from. Simply format it before passing it to the HTML component

Comment: can u show me an example if the data comes from an endpoin and then how to pass it !! am so sorry but am new in this .. and thanks.