# Returns only one object JSON instead multiple objects PHP?

Tags: php, json

Firstly, please take a look this JSON
[http://ws.luyencong.net/data/search/query.php?do=json](http://ws.luyencong.net/data/search/query.php)

Here is it's code:

```
/* --- Execute query and get the data. --- */
$query = $db->query("SELECT t.* FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t");
while($data = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    $results[] = array($data['subject'] => $data['subject']);
    $json = json_encode($results, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}

/* --- Print the results to the screen, for future purposes. --- */
echo $json;
```

But I want the output JSON format will look like this: http://ws.luyencong.net/data/search/json.txt

Help will be appreciated. Thanks for anything.

Have a good day!

Comment: So you want us to tell you to wrap your JSON with []? :)

Comment: Please include a simple example: how the output looks now, how should look. The output from the links is unreadable.

Comment: you want a json hash which has keys like `B\u1ed1 c\u00e1o th\u00e0nh l\u1eadp di\u1ec5n \u0111\u00e0n Luy\u1ec7n C\u00f4ng`?

Comment: You want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097374/php-pretty-print-json-encode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you just want to change this:

```
$results[] = array($data['subject'] => $data['subject']);
```

To this:

```
$results[$data['subject']] = $data['subject'];
```

And, as @Orangepill suggested, move your `json_encode` call out of the loop. So your entire solution would look like this:

```
/* --- Execute query and get the data. --- */
$query = $db->query("SELECT t.* FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t");
$results = array();
while($data = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    $results[$data['subject']] = $data['subject'];
}

/* --- Print the results to the screen, for future purposes. --- */
echo json_encode($results, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to move your json_encode call outside of the loop.

```
/* --- Execute query and get the data. --- */
$query = $db->query("SELECT t.* FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads t");
while($data = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    $results[$data['subject']] = $data['subject'];
}
$json = json_encode($results, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
/* --- Print the results to the screen, for future purposes. --- */
echo $json;
```

Comment: but why the hell the key is the same as the value? shouldnt it be array('subject'=>$data['subject']);

Comment: @steven only the op would know for sure..

Comment: Your answer does not reformat the json as the OP has asked.

Comment: This will make the code more efficient but as the `$json` variable gets overwritten every time in the loop, the end-result will be exactly the same.

Comment: Updated to reformat as op requested

Comment: @jeroen $json assignment is out side of the loop...$json is not reassigned.

Comment: I was comparing your previous version to the OP's version where the variable gets overwritten and ends up being the same as yours in the last iteration of the loop...

Comment: @steven : Because all datas in this JSON are thread titles in my forum, then now I want to add auto-suggestion to the forum so the key must be same as the value because of the jQuery plugin I'm using will need them for sure...

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting your arrays.  It looks like you only want to have a single JSON object rather than an array of them.  So change your setting of the `$result` to be:

```
$results[$data['subject']] = $data['subject'];
```

Then as suggested move the `json_encode` outside of the loop, you don't need to do that until after the array has been populated.  You are just overwriting the variable over and over again for no reason.