# Json_encode()  with output

Tags: php, json

Hard to understand (json_encode) i'm using the code:

```
<?php

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY ID");
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $titel = $fetch[title];
    $post = array('items' => array( 0 => array('title' => "$title", 'description' => "$title")));


    echo json_encode($post);

}
?>
```

Output:

```
  {"items":[{"title":"title","description":"title"}]}
{"items":[{"title":"title","description":"title"}]}
```

But i want an output like:

```
{

"items": [

{
"title":"title",
"description":"title"
},
{
"title":"title",
"description":"title"
},
{
"title":"title",
"description":"title"
}

]

}
```

Can someone please help me to get an output like the code above?

Comment: Google "JSON formatter" and you'll probably find some code to format JSON in PHP.

Comment: You could try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php

Comment: Are you want to match with js json and php json?

Comment: To current and future answerers/commenters: please note that the structure of what the OP wants and what he has is *not* the same, so it's not a matter of just reformatting the output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY ID");
$post = array();
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $titel = $fetch[title];
    $post['items'][] = array('title' => "$title", 'description' => "$title");
}
echo json_encode($post);
?>
```

Edit: correction

Comment: +1 I misread his question, and you got it spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Create items as an array before the loop, append inside the loop, then put it in $post and encode it after the loop.