# How to output a properly formatted JSON from a PHP file?

Tags: json

I have this code:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT');

    $data = array(
        "data" => array(
            "sender" => "Jhon Andrew",
            "recipient" => "Someone OverThe Internet",
            "conversation" =>
            array(
                "unix" => "1234567890",
                "message" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
            ),
            array(
                "unix" => "0987654321",
                "message" => "Tema tis rolod muspi merol."
            )
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

And I was expecting this kind of result:

```
{
    "data": {
        "sender":"Jhon Andrew",
        "recipient":"Someone OverThe Internet",
        "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    }
}
```

But I got it displayed in just one line, like this:

```
{"data":{"sender":"Jhon Andrew","recipient":"Someone OverThe Internet","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."}}
```

How can I get properly formatted JSON output just like what I am expecting? It's not really important actually, but I just want to see the result in good format.

---

> ...by the way, I just copied the headers from facebooks graph link
>   because that is how I want to output the result. Example:
>   graph.facebook.com/mOngsAng.gA

---

> It is valid of course. All I want to know is how to output it like
>   this: graph.facebook.com/mOngsAng.gA - As you can see it is properly
>   formatted. I mean it has line breaks and indentions. Unlike what I am
>   getting is just showed in one line.

Comment: ...by the way, I just copied the headers from facebooks graph link because that is how I want to output the result. Example: http://graph.facebook.com/mOngsAng.gA

Comment: Did you try PHP's `json_encode()` function?

Comment: @parker.sikand Yes, I did. As you can see in the PHP code I showed.

Comment: Why is this not valid JSON for you?

Comment: I answered too quickly... I am not sure how to format the way you want. But ultimately the formatting should not matter... your result is perfectly valid JSON...

Comment: It is valid of course. All I want to know is how to output it like this: http://graph.facebook.com/mOngsAng.gA - As you can see it is properly formatted. I mean it has line breaks and indentions. Unlike what I am getting is just showed in one line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty-Printing JSON with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag of [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) in php manual.
You can simply use:

```
$data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

If you aren't using `PHP 5.4` or greater try with the accepted answer of the question: [Pretty-Printing JSON with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php).

However, yours is a **valid** json output!

Comment: This is just what I need however I am getting an error, maybe because of my PHP version. I am now reading the link you gave.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now have my expected result. I just used this PHP function: http://recursive-design.com/blog/2008/03/11/format-json-with-php/ - since I am using PHP version lower than 5.4 | And for people has the same as my problem and using PHP 5.4+ "JSON_PRETTY_PRINT" will do the trick. Thanks again! :]