# Laravel 4 JSON Output formatting

Tags: php, json, laravel

```
return Response::json(array(
    'status' => 200,
    'posts' => $post->toArray()
), 200);
```

Using the code above I returned data in json format.
I have seen other api's that return json giving it back in formatted view.
Like:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=440&count=3&maxlength=300&format=json
```

But mine is returning it in one line. How do I generate the json in a formatted way with laravel?

---

**update**

I cannot test the code yet until I tomorrow. So I'll accept the answer tom.

But this is the api

```
http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Facades.Response.html
```

and the parameters are,

```
$data
$status
$headers
```

---

**update**

Actually I modified the response class of illuminate to have that constant.

Comment: you have solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php

Answer (score 18):

It is possible in current 4.2 version.

```
Response::json($data=[], $status=200, $headers=[], $options=JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/417f539803ce96eeab7b420d8b03f04959a603e9

Answer (score 7):

I don't think Laravel allows you to format the JSON output. However, you can do it using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode)'s [`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) constant (available since PHP 5.4.0). Here's how:

```
$array = array(
    'status' => 200,
    'posts' => $post->toArray()
);

return json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Why first making a response and then decode and encode again? The variant by @XoneFobic is better.

Comment: @Reflic: Definitely needs moar coffee. Updated the post, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The same answer but with the json content-type (like the example in the question):

```
return Response::make(json_encode(array(
    'status' => 200,
    'posts' => $post->toArray()
), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))->header('Content-Type', "application/json");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is (to my knowledge) a server-side setting.
Like xDebug will format it like that (also colours it).

By default, JSON is a single string. And isn't related to Laravel or any other framework.

If you're using PHP 5.4+ You could use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`

```
return json_encode(array(
    'status' => 200,
    'posts' => $post->toArray()
), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Untested and you could look in Laravel api if it's possible to use Response::json() for it.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.2 you can use a similar approach using the helpers

```
return response()->json($data=[], $status=200, $headers=[], $options=JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
```