# Display JSON on UI

Tags: php, html, json

Maybe i am wrong but i can not find anyone who wants to display a json message just in json format from url on the page except for me.
I have a webshop in html, javascript and css. I am looking for some code example to display the json message just on the page. I don't want to parse the json into html or what else. I just want to display the json message as it is like this format: `{"success":0,"message":"User not known"}`.
This message above is the url response from my php database in xampp.
Below is my code and it works good, the problem is that this code is static. I am looking for some dynamic solution where you enter the url and it responds with json message. Any help is appriciated.

this is my login.html

```
if(form.id.value == "" || form.pass.value == "")  {       
alert("Empty details!");
}else if (form.id.value=="johan" && form.pass.value=="123") {             
location="Page2.html" 
} else  { alert("Wrong username or password!")
       }
           }
```

and this is the json read:

```
// 1 - read josn:
var my_json_output = {"success":1,"message":"Vol","Username":"jan","UserSurname":"janman"}',
json_yes.succes json_yes = JSON.parse(my_json_output);
    var my_json_output = '{"success":0,"message":"User_Unknown"}',
    json_no = JSON.parse(my_json_output);
        if(json_no.success == 1) { alert("Welcome, " + s + json_yes.Username);
        }else if(json_no.success == 0) { alert("Try again");     
}
```

Comment: Pretty-Printing JSON with PHP :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php

Comment: What you're looking for is how to serialize the data you're reading from your database into json. We need more code showing how your reading the data from your database.

Comment: Hi Naser, On your request i added some more codes. I hope this enough is otherwise i will give more details if needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now i could find the answer and will share with others: just make a variable from XMLHttpRequest(); and use that variable for the message:
    myconnect = new XMLHttpRequest();