# creating json object from sql database using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to create a json object from my mysql database for a android project. I need an output something like this:

```
{
    "feed": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "National Geographic Channel",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/cosmos.jpg",
            "status": "\"Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor,\" says Brannon Braga, executive producer and director. \"And Cosmos is all about making science an experience.\"",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/nat.jpg",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "TIME",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time_best.jpg",
            "status": "30 years of Cirque du Soleil's best photos",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": "http://ti.me/1qW8MLB"
        }
]
}
```

But I am getting ouput something like this:

```
{"feed":[{"id":"0","name":"punith","image":"","status":"ucfyfcyfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff","profilePic":"http:\/\/api.androidhive.info\/feed\/img\/nat.jpg","timestamp":"1403375851930","url":""}]}
```

Everything is on a single line and the `id` attribute should not be quotes. Is there anything I could do.This is my php file

```
<?php
define('HOST','');
define('USER','');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql = "select * from timeline";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('id'=>$row[0],
'name'=>$row[1],
'image'=>$row[2],
'status'=>$row[3],
'profilePic'=>$row[4],
'timestamp'=>$row[5],
'url'=>$row[6]
));
}

echo json_encode(array("feed"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

And will it affect if the output is on a single line.
The database contains exactly the same columns used as attributes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can specify `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` as the second parameter of [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Your question and explanation at the end helped me to create a complex json without resorting to JSON_* functions of mysql.   $jres = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    array_push($jres, 
      array('value' => $row[0], 'data' => 
        array(
          'last' => $row[0],
          'expcode' => $row[1]
        )
      )
    );
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ID in quotes**

ID is in quotes because it is a string, not an integer. You can change that by changing this:

```
array('id'=>$row[0]
```

to this:

```
array('id'=>intval($row[0])
```

---

**"Pretty Printing"**

Putting it on multiple lines will only affect readability but not how the data is computed - but you can prettify it: [Pretty-Printing JSON with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)

```
$output = json_encode(array("feed"=>$result), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding with **JSON_PRETTY_PRINT**

```
$json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

where `data` is your result array.

in your case

```
echo json_encode(array("feed"=>$result),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

refer this [Tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) from the official PHP docs .

Answer (score 0):

Aswell as the other answers, it would be more semantic to include the json header, I've found that just including this also helps with the appearance of the json itself so that it is formatted properly and not all one continuous string.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

For php>5.4

```
$json=json_encode(array("feed"=>$result),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print_r($json);
```