# Formatting Laravel's Data before returning

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to have the returning data formatted as shown below:

```
{
  "cols": [
            {
              "label":"Topping",
              "type":"string"
            },
            {
              "label":"Slices",
              "type":"number"
            }
          ],
  "rows": [
            {
              "c":[
                    {"v":"Mushrooms"},
                    {"v":3}
                  ]
            },
            {
              "c":[
                    {"v":"Onions"},
                    {"v":1}
                  ]
            },
            {
              "c":[
                    {"v":"Olives"},
                    {"v":1}
                  ]
            },
            {
              "c":[
                    {"v":"Zucchini"},
                    {"v":1}
                  ]
            },
            {
              "c":[
                    {"v":"Pepperoni"},
                    {"v":2}
                  ]
            }
          ]
}
```

Is there any way to do this in Laravel?

Comment: Data may be anything, I just want to know how can I format it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your db:

```
/*
Table: label_type
Column: label       type
    Topping     string
    Slices      number

Table: Some_Food

Column: name        quantity
     Mushrooms  3
     Onions     1
     Olives     1
     Zucchini   1
     Pepperoni  2
*/
$label_type = DB::table('label_type')->get();
$cols = array();

foreach($label_type as $item1)

{
$arr = array([
    'label'=>$item1->label,
    'type' =>$item1->type
]); 
$cols = array_merge_recursive($cols, $arr);
}

$foods = DB::table('Some_Food')->get();

$rows = array();
foreach($foods as $item2)

{   
    $arr1 = array(['v'=>$item2->name]); 
    $arr2 = array(['v'=>$item2->quantity]);
    $c = array_merge_recursive($arr1,$arr2);
    $mage = array(['c'=>$c]);
    $rows = array_merge_recursive($rows, $mage);
}
$result = array(['cols'=>$cols,'rows'=>$rows]);
echo dd($result);
```

Or you just test, view my code (Laravel 5):

```
        $label = array('Topping','Slices');
        $type = array('string','number');
        $cols = array();
        for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
        {
            $arr = array([
                'label'=>$label[$i],
                'type' =>$type[$i]
            ]);
            $cols = array_merge_recursive($cols, $arr);
        }

        $name = array('Mushrooms','Onions','Olives','Zucchini','Pepperoni');
        $quantity = array(3,1,1,1,2);

        $rows = array();
        for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
        {
            $arr1 = array(['v'=>$name[$i]]);
            $arr2 = array(['v'=>$quantity[$i]]);
            $c = array_merge_recursive($arr1,$arr2);
            $mage = array(['c'=>$c]);
            $rows = array_merge_recursive($rows, $mage);
        }
        $result = array(['cols'=>$cols,'rows'=>$rows]);
        echo dd($result);
```

[image: Result]