# Converting Mysql data into JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
<?php
include("WIP/dbconnect.php")
?>
</head>

<?php
$link = Connection();
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `testLocation`.`Date`, 
    `testLocation`.`Serial`, `testLocation`.`State`, 
    `testLocation`.`Count` FROM `testLocation`",$link);

if($result!==FALSE){
    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

I am currently trying to convert some data from my mysql database into json format but for some reason the data being produced isn't in a good format. It looks like this
[Data Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS6xH.png)

I got the JSON data to format correctly but I am unable to generate the graph.  I am currently using AmCharts.com to generate the graph.  It says Cannot Parse Json

```
  <script>

  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "dataLoader": {
      "url": "index2.php"
    },
    "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/",
    "categoryField": "Date",
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00",
    "startDuration": 1,
    "categoryAxis": {
      "parseDates": true
    },
    "graphs": [ {
      "valueField": "Serial",
      "bullet": "round",
      "bulletBorderColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
      "lineThickness ": 2,
      "lineAlpha": 0.5
    }, {
      "valueField": "State",
      "bullet": "round",
      "bulletBorderColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
      "lineThickness ": 2,
      "lineAlpha": 0.5
    }, {
      "valueField": "Count",
      "bullet": "round",
      "bulletBorderColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
      "lineThickness ": 2,
      "lineAlpha": 0.5
    }]   } );
```

Comment: [Is this what you're trying to do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)

Comment: I actually got the JSON to work, it validates but I am unable to graph it using amCharts, it says unable to Parse

Comment: Does `makeChart` expect a JSON string or an object?

Comment: From what I'm reading on the documentation it  is makeChart(container, config, delay) The div tag, and the configuration

Answer (score 1):

If you use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` you will just get only an assoc array and not an assoc array and a numeric array together.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

If you were to use `mysql_fetch_object()` then you could easily generate an array of objects like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

> [`Manual mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)
>
> [`Manual mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)
>
> [`Manual mysql_fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: I changed it to fetch_object and it looks better, but they are appearing side by side, how do I have it appear line by line?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand your question

Comment: Remember JSON is data represented as a STRING. There is no visual formatting in a JSON String.

Comment: Alright so I validated the JSON data but for some reason it won't parse.  I am currently trying to use amCharts.com to create the graph.  I posted the code for the amCharts above.

Comment: I am afraid that constitutes a second question. You will have to ask that as another question, or it is going to get lost