# Why are these two APIs displayed differently in the browser?

Tags: php

Our API and GitHub's both return JSON text content.

[GitHub's API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sG6t.png) in the browser is displayed wrapped in a `<pre>` tag and in monospace font.

However, [our API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGrr2.png) is displayed in serif font without any wrapper.

Why is it displayed in a different font when both responses are JSON?

Comment: How is this a comparision? One are square brackets and the other sample are curly ones. Or what exactly is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty-Printing JSON with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)

Comment: op see the comment section of the accepted answer in the question link above for instructions on setting the content header and pretty printing the json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try refreshing the GitHub page with the `Network` tab open. You will see among the Response Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

(If it's a cached response then you won't see that header - try another GitHub link though and you'll see it)

GitHub is setting this ContentType header on their response. Chrome recognizes that the response is JSON, so it formats it with a `<pre>` tag wrapped around it to make it easier to read.

Your API is returning plain text, therefore Chrome doesn't recognize it as JSON.

Comment: Ah thank you. Stupid question but thanks for the serious answer.

Comment: @voku No problem, not a stupid question. Sometimes it's just hard to even know what to ask. I knew what you meant immediately and I tried to get my answer in before the question got closed