# Add json to array without lose format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I tried to add the simple json below to my array in my API

```
$result = array();
...
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
$json =  json_encode($arr);               
$result['json'] = $json;

return $result;
```

But after add it to my array, it loose the format like this.

**Please look at the red arrow point to and compare with screenshot 2.**

[image]
What I want is my json should display like

[image]

How can I prevent it. Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated

Comment: What are you expecting it to be? You've taken an *associative* array and turned it into a JSON string (which defines an "object" in JSON terminology, because it's an associative array, not a numeric-index array), then added that string to you result.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have update my question. please help me, i'm very new in PHP, I have searched but still don't find the answer

Comment: Both screenshots show equivalent JSON strings. What is the problem? Surely you are not going to occupy yourself with white-space? And that the double quotes are escaped in the first screenshot, is only normal since the whole string is quoted in double quotes, it has to be like that, but the string itself does not *store* those backslashes... it is notation only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty-Printing JSON with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)

Comment: @trincot I have update my question, please check it again. thank you so much

Comment: Your latest screenshot shows a property called `json` which is **not** JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) What you have there is just an object or an associative array within an overall JSON structure, and [Heinrich](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39685892/157247) is correct about what's going on.

Comment: thank you for your explain, I will look at this. and the solution add array to array solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to be happening here is double encoding, your $result array gets encoded as well, then it encodes the $result['json'] again, causing the output you are seeing.

```
$result = array();
...
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
$json =  json_encode($arr);               
$result['json'] = $json;

return $result; // either you are using a framework, or not showing a step, but this also seems to be encoded before being sent back to the client.
```

Given what I can infer from you have then shown us, do not encode your array before assigning it to $result['json']

```
$result = array();
...          
$result['json'] = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

return $result;
```

Should then give you what you want.

Comment: The question remains very unclear, but this is the closest interpretation I can make of it, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
$result['json']= array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
$json =  json_encode($result);               

return $json;
```

this solution is working for me .