# Retrieving JSON form data in php

Tags: php, json

I've got a HTML5 game that encodes character data into JSON then uses POST to send it to a php file.
This is what the formdata looks like

```
{"onScreen":3,"quoteNum":4,"CHARACTER1":{"screenPos":1,"charNum":0,"bodyNum":0,"hairNum":0,"eyeNum":0,"hairColNum":0,"name":""},"CHARACTER2":{"screenPos":2,"charNum":0,"bodyNum":0,"hairNum":0,"eyeNum":0,"hairColNum":0,"name":""},"CHARACTER3":{"screenPos":3,"charNum":0,"bodyNum":0,"hairNum":0,"eyeNum":0,"hairColNum":0,"name":""}}:
```

The only problem is I don't know how to retrieve the encoded JSON in php.
When I simply try to print the data php just prints "array".

How do I simply get php to print the JSON data it was posted?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the encoded json on server side like this after decoding it to array.

```
print '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($_POST,1)) 
print '</pre>'
```

**For your info:** your json string contains a colon at the end :P