# How to make pretty json in php and remove the first and last curli braces

Tags: php, json, httprequest

Am getting json results in php as follows:

```
{ "dataset": [{"seriesname": "Soap","data": [ { "value": "90000" }]},{"seriesname": "Dummy","data": [ { "value": "70000" }]} ]}
```

Pls help me in making pretty and removing the first and last curly braces

I want the result in this way:

```
 "dataset": [{"seriesname": "Soap","data": [ { "value": "90000" }]},{"seriesname": "Dummy","data": [ { "value": "70000" }]} ]
```

Comment: ... but your preferred version *isn't* a vaid JSON?!

Comment: for what purpose you want to print pretty json ? see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)

Comment: You should take a look to your php array conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove first and last curly braces:

```
$string = '{ "dataset": [{"seriesname": "Soap","data": [ { "value": "90000" }]},{"seriesname": "Dummy","data": [ { "value": "70000" }]} ]}';

echo $result = substr($string, 1, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want isn't json. But if you really want it, you could just use trim to remove the leading and trailing curly brakets.

```
$noJson = trim($json, "{}");
```

if it is important, that you just remove one curly, you should maybe use an regex

```
$noJson = preg_replace('/\{(.*)\}/', '$1', $json);
```