# How to change an element of an array into object?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am fetching data from a table having different columns then I saved it in a array. Here is my code:

```
$sql="SELECT image,image1,image2,image3,image4,image5 FROM `app_places` where place_id='".$place_id."'  ";
    $check= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($check);
    //var_dump($rowcount);
    if($rowcount<=0)
    {
        $minfo = array("success"=>'false',"msg"=>'invalid place_id');
        $jsondata = json_encode($minfo);
        print_r($jsondata);
        exit(); 

        }
        else
        {
            $data = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check,MYSQLI_NUM))
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
```

I encode this in json format and my out is like this:

```
{"allplaces":
[
{
"image":"http://www.freepngimg.com/download/lion/3-2-lion-png.png","image1":"http://mobileappdatabase.in/city/uploads/default-image/defaultimage.png","image2":"http://mobileappdatabase.in/city/uploads/default-image/defaultimage.png","image3":"http://mobileappdatabase.in/city/uploads/default-image/defaultimage.png","image4":"http://mobileappdatabase.in/city/uploads/default-image/defaultimage.png","image5":"http://mobileappdatabase.in/city/uploads/default-image/defaultimage.png"
}
]
}
```

But I need like this :

```
     {"allplaces":[
    {"image":"http://www.freepngimg.com/download/lion/3-2-lion-png.png"},
{"image1":"http://mobileappdatabase.in/city/uploads/default-image/defaultimage.png"},

{"image2":"http://mobileappdatabase.in/city/uploads/default-image/defaultimage.png"},

{"image3":"http://mobileappdatabase.in/city/uploads/default-image/defaultimage.png"},

{"image4":"http://mobileappdatabase.in/city/uploads/default-image/defaultimage.png"},

{"image5":"http://mobileappdatabase.in/city/uploads/default-image/defaultimage.png"}]}
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names, alarm bells should start ringing. Review the basic principles of database design.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php

Answer (score 0):

This is only going to work if you have 1 row. Your table structure is pretty bad, but here you go.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
     $data[] = array(
       $key => $value
     );
    }    
}
```

Comment: this not giving me what i want i want every element as a object as i state up