# JSON decode api from db-ip.com using PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl, file-get-contents

I have some problem with db-ip.com api that display info about visitor ip's. My script only print < pre > tags but nothing between. I need that all parameters from api are decoded and print, like from this link: http://db-ip.com/178.133.109.106.
Please help me.

```
<?php

// get ip
if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])){

    $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];

}

elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])){

    $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

}

else {

    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

}



$json_url = "http://api.db-ip.com/v2/free/$ip";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json=str_replace('}, ]',"} ]",$json);
$data = json_decode($json);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty-Printing JSON with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)

Comment: That means `json_decode()` is getting an error. What does `json_last_error()` return?

Comment: Use `http:` instead of `https:`. You have to use the paid version to use HTTPS. But you should have gotten JSON with the error message.

Comment: @Barmar.. no error

Comment: @Barmar i use http:... as you can see in script

Comment: Sorry, I confused it with the https in the question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    // get ip
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); //$ip = '178.133.109.106';

    $json_url = "http://api.db-ip.com/v2/free/$ip";
    $data = file_get_contents($json_url);
    print_r($data);

?>
```

check out this link 
http://tpcg.io/Gv3KLv

Comment: Thank you, but... Script display this "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: I tested this code and it works, but based on your Error, you probably have an unexpected character at the first line @КатеринаМусакина

Comment: you can see how it works here: http://taxi.ho.ua/g - this page have only your script