# Laravel write model info pretty

Tags: laravel, logging, printing

Hi I want to record a lot of models before and after modification.

Yeah. I know there is dirty() and isclean() things.

But I have to record all data before and after , so I could check which model has problem to updateOrCreate.

I do this.

```php
 Log::info( $myModel );
```

it is written on log file.

```sh
local.INFO: {"id":90638719,"target_id":1,"time":1595178000,.... }
```

I want make it pretty ..

Does someone have an idea about this?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by __check which model has problem to updateOrCreate__? To print the object prettier in logs you can use `Log::info(json_encode($myModel, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9120871/3226121)

Comment: Thanks... What is what I looking for.