# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 44498 of the JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json, qcubed

There are many similar issues addressed in this forum. But I couldn't get smarter about my problem. I will describe briefly.

I have developed a nestedSortable QCubed platform. Everything is fine, but one thing remained unresolved. Sorting and deleting are fine.
Adding a new entry FOR THE FIRST TIME strikes: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 44498 of the JSON data".

Creating the following entries will not cause any problems.

[image]

I checked with Debugger and found the place that throws the error:

```
// Opera 10-11 does not throw on post-comma invalid pseudos
     div.querySelectorAll ("* ,: x");
     rbuggyQSA.push (",. *:");``
```

I tried both versions: jquery-1.12.4.js or jquery-3.2.1.js. There are no differences.

I also checked json via https://jsonlint.com/, then the json output is validated.

I am grateful if someone can draw my attention or suggest what I should look for and do.

Comment: Have you checked what is in the JSON at (around) column 44498 where the error shows up in the content.

Comment: I understood so much and couldn't find an answer, that's why I posted my clarifying question here.
Please don't hit me on how I find json's voluminous stream column 44498. Do you have a tip on how to find this place quickly?

Comment: (Sorry I've been busy) It's difficult as a lot of editors have problems with data in one huge line.  Is the data generated in PHP or something else.  If PHP, you could try using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php to layout the data in a more useful way.

Comment: I'm sorry I was busy in the meantime. I checked several times and found no errors because it is not possible. Then I was reminded to check for updates to the QCubed v4 version. And in the meantime, updates had come. I updated and this problem disappeared.

Thanks to everyone who tried to guide me. I close this topic.