# How can I do this change in json?

Tags: php, json

Hi I have php code which I use json_encode to create from an array a json code, the thing or porblem is that json_encode becomes the array to a lineal json what I mean it this:

```
    $data["auth"]["cert"] = ["-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n6L0=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "pkey-data" => "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nCvLdtcSmumV5hxnVdtwjdlQD\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"];
    $data["emisor"] = "76063822-6";
    $data["resolucion"] = ["fecha" => "2014-06-17", "numero" => 57];
    $data["secuencia"] = 1;
    $data["documentos"][] = [
        "TpoDoc" => 39, 
        "NroDoc" => 3, 
        "TasaImp" => 0, 
        "FchDoc" => "2021-07-05", 
        "MntExe" => 100, 
        "MntNeto" => 0, 
        "MntIVA" => 0, 
        "MntTotal" => 100
       ];

    $data = json_encode($data);
```

That array becomes to this:

```
{"auth":{"cert":{"cert-data":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIGjjCCBXagAwIBAgIDAR4jMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGmMQswCQYDVQQGEwJD\nTDEYMBYGA1UEChMPQWNlcHRhLmNvbSBTLkEuMUgwRgYDVQQDEz9BY2VwdGEuY29t\nIEF1dG9yaWRhZCBDZXJ0aWZpY2Fkb3JhIENsYXNlIDMgUGVyc29uYSBOYXR1cmFs\nIC0gRzQxHjAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWD2luZm9AYWNlcHRhLmNvbTETMBEGA1UEBRMK\nOTY5MTkwNTAtODAeFw0yMTA3MDgyMzQwMjZaFw0yNDA3MDgyMzQwMjZaMIGXMQsw\nCQYDVQQGEwJDTDEYMBYGA1UEDBMPUEVSU09OQSBOQVRVUkFMMSswKQYDVQQDEyJN\nQVJDRUxPIEFMRUpBTkRSTyBJTlpVTlpBIEdPTlpBTEVaMSwwKgYJKoZIhvcNAQkB\nFh1DUklTVElBTklOWlVOWkFASklTUEFSS0lORy5DTDETMBEGA1UEBRMKMTAwMzM3\nNDEtSzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAK/zoDtqd7+qB7aX\njS/kiBnLOf62orrMMdL3G22l0NJBziWVv/DezIgoFONUEF2XNXBWNAKTbLABvGIZ\nNFLyE4QuevdLd5AXuOt0q4+Y2msZemrP3zIkuT1dkNo/djj5gmFY3hC1i9DEj2ZQ\nF3kwcN9rrhQrzg3I0ixrRfdozMIypvCY4pWoJOvaNc8Z1a2Brq09QXQ3zUB3jXW7\nezxQlOCqv6G37UB9FzInnwAmicz5/92YtvFAXXJd4dtuaoPQt7Hn8XzhP8wmtj9j\nE9uHUbzK4CmQm4bYb1hmceg4crTHybTLUHngSlfI7QbDsLroaUlNgq8Kte8qDNxg\nqAhLkW0CAwEAAaOCAtAwggLMMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFKr9vcXpN032mU1XjsFxGvnr\nwwbjMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQYpMku0lGJKNQdxadkxl0mirm7uTALBgNVHQ8EBAMCBPAw\nHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwIGCCsGAQUFBwMEMBEGCWCGSAGG+EIBAQQEAwIF\noDCB+gYDVR0gBIHyMIHvMIHsBggrBgEEAbVrAjCB3zAxBggrBgEFBQcCARYlaHR0\ncHM6Ly9hY2c0LmFjZXB0YS5jb20vQ1BTLUFjZXB0YWNvbTCBqQYIKwYBBQUHAgIw\ngZwwFhYPQWNlcHRhLmNvbSBTLkEuMAMCAQIagYFFbCB0aXR1bGFyIGhhIHNpZG8g\ndmFsaWRhZG8gZW4gZm9ybWEgcHJlc2VuY2lhbCwgcXVlsZGFuZG8gaGFiaWxpdGFk\nbyBlbCBDZXJ0aWZpY2FkbyBwYXJhIHVzbyB0cmlidXRhcmlvLCBwYWdvcywgY29t\nZXJjaW8geSBvdHJvcy4wWgYDVR0SBFMwUaAYBggrBgEEAcEBAqAMFgo5NjkxOTA1\nMC04oCQGCCsGAQUFBwgDoBgwFgwKOTY5MTkwNTAtOAYIKwYBBAHBAQKBD2luZm9A\nYWNlcHRhLmNvbTBoBgNVHREEYTBfoBgGCCsGAQQBwQEBoAwWCjEwMDMzNzQxLUug\nJAYIKwYBBQUHCAOgGDAWDAoxMDAzMzc0MS1LBggrBgEEAcEBAoEdQ1JJU1RJQU5J\nTlpVTlpBQEpJU1BBUktJTkcuQ0wwRwYIKwYBBQUHAQEEOzA5MDcGCCsGAQUFBzAB\nhitodHRwczovL2FjZzQuYWNlcHRhLmNvbS9hY2c0L29jc3AvQ2xhc2UzLUc0MD8G\nA1UdHwQ4MDYwNKAyoDCGLmh0dHBzOi8vYWNnNC5hY2VwdGEuY29tL2FjZzQvY3Js\nL0NsYXNlMy1HNC5jcmwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAAyvyBRFLpuF947AuBDm\nllTVh2Txrn2TK8bCl0iljnaCOdG3idmE5x9Ta7anzV0fL+ujQrUsSd7fa1n4PN9a\nn5rBmC/HR1DhBm4WIoVbVy3oz1GT2bmnfLOBqNKMvFNX0MJoOwYIkPxUcwRZXoPe\n6qe4tp4LAQiIUSxIbtVflXrctqX9m8PYf5wNA8gkiKK4qp8h+d+ZySAEHVFlHWb8\nY6TznjIwY05T46ATEyOVagDSijwW1Nj8m/8eJTF0vDKIzW6Uaa7YIPzVnkV0IHyE\nTyRne1CdJvynaEgs/BX84I1ovtsH2iEDX83xmKxtrdtPgO+Qin0kqHEu1EaEj9Qt\n6L0=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----","pkey-data":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nCvLdtcSmumV5hxnVdtwjdlQD\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"}},"emisor":"76063822-6","resolucion":{"fecha":"2014-06-17","numero":57},"secuencia":1,"documentos":[{"TpoDoc":39,"NroDoc":3,"TasaImp":0,"FchDoc":"2021-07-05","MntExe":100,"MntNeto":0,"MntIVA":0,"MntTotal":100}]}
```

I mean in a json of one line BUT I need this kind of json:

```
 {
 "auth":{
  "cert":{
     "cert-data":"-",
     "pkey-data":""
  }
 },
 "emisor":"76063822-6",
 "resolucion":{
   "fecha":"2014-06-17",
   "numero":57
 },
 "secuencia":1,
 "documentos":[
  {
     "TpoDoc":39,
     "NroDoc":3,
     "TasaImp":0,
     "FchDoc":"2021-07-05",
     "MntExe":100,
     "MntNeto":0,
     "MntIVA":0,
     "MntTotal":100
  }
 ]
}
```

How you can see this json is not in one line I wonder how can I transform that lineal json to this kind of json if I am using json_encode?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty-Printing JSON with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just format it this way:

```
$data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php