# How to unescape Javascript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like “\u00ed” to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-char)

I have some javascript text that contains values like '\u003c' (less than sign <).

Is there a php functions that allows me to unescape javascript ?

(I did not expect urldecode to work, though i tried it. It does not indeed.)

Comment: Dominic, this worked thanx ! I did not notice the duplicate because of the pretty verbose title :) It's like another question :P You make it an answer if you like, i will vote for it.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>yep, would just suggest it, `urldecode();`</strike>

Try:

```
<?php
  function utf8_urldecode($str) {
    $str = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($str));
    return html_entity_decode($str,null,'UTF-8');;
  }
?>
```

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php#79595)