# How to turn Unicode "encoded" string into "plain" string using PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like “\u00ed” to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-char)

I've a string:

`\u0068\u0074\u0074\u0070`

how to, using PHP (built-in function?) turn it into a string:?

`http`