# How to decode '\u0040' to '@' using PHP

Tags: php, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like “\u00ed” to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-char)

Which PHP function can decode string

> foo\u0040foo.com

to

> foo@foo.com

How it works?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The usual reason for this question is handling JSON, in which case the answer is to use a proper JSON parser (eg `json_decode`) and not attempt to fix the string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only ever going to be that one specific character, you could just do a simple `str_replace('\u0040','@',$string)`.