# How to pull specific content from HTML using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

How do I go about pulling specific content from a given live online HTML page?

For example: http://www.gumtree.com/p/for-sale/ovation-semi-acoustic-guitar/93991967

I want to retrieve the text description, the path to the main image and the price only. So basically, I want to retrieve content which is inside specific divs with maybe specific IDs or classes inside a html page.

Psuedo code

```
$page = load_html_contents('http://www.gumtr..');
$price = getPrice($page);
$description = getDescription($page);
$title = getTitle($page);
```

Please note I do not intend to steal any content from gumtree, or anywhere else for that matter, I am just providing an example.

Comment: TOS for gum tree prohibit this.

Comment: I'm not intending to steal any content from gumtree, it's just an example.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: heard that one before ;)

Comment: hope this link will help you to get data from different url  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810735/html-parsing-get-data-from-a-table-inside-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial [Easy web scraping with PHP](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/web-scrape-with-php-tutorial) recommended by robotrobert is good to start, I have made several comments in it. For a better performance use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/). Among other things handles HTTP headers, SSL, cookies, proxies, etc. Cookies is something that you must  pay attention.

I just found [HTML Parsing and Screen Scraping with the Simple HTML DOM Library](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/). Is more advanced, facilitates and speed up the page parsing through a DOM parser (instead regular expressions --enough hard to master and resources consuming). I recommend you this last one 100%.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what u wanna do, is called WEBSCRAPING. 
Basically, u load into the html content into one variable, so u will need to use regexps to search for specific ids..etc.
Search after webscraping.

[HERE is a basic tutorial](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/web-scrape-with-php-tutorial)

[THIS book should be useful too.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271204)

Answer (score 2):

something like this would be a good starting point if you wanted tabular output

```
$raw=file_get_contents($url) or die('could not select');
$newlines=array("\t","\n","\r","\x20\x20","\0","\x0B","<br/>");
$content=str_replace($newlines, "", html_entity_decode($raw));
$start=strpos($content,'<some id> ');
$end = strpos($content,'</ending id>');
$table = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);
preg_match_all("|<tr(.*)</tr>|U",$table,$rows);
foreach ($rows[0] as $row){
if ((strpos($row,'<th')===false)){
 // array to vars
preg_match_all("|<td(.*)</td>|U",$row,$cells);
$var1= strip_tags($cells[0][0]); 
$var2= strip_tags($cells[0][1]);
```

etc etc

Comment: file_get_contents might need to be replaced with curl. file_get_contents has been disabled on my shared hosting account for example... but does work on localhost