# How to decode (\u00D8 \u00A7 \u00D) in php

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, decode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like “\u00ed” to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)

I have requested a `URL` using `REST` in `PHP` and I got this result

```
\u00D8 \u00A7 \u00D9 \ i \u00B3 \u016E\ \u00D8 \u00A7 \u00D9 ... \u00B9 i \u016E \ \u016E Z\u0679z \u0192 ...
```

but when I request the URL directly from the bowser I get the result as plain readable text

what is this encoding, and how to decode it using `PHP` to readable text ?

### REST client code

I have called this function

```
$result = RestClient::get($url);
```

.

```
<? 



/** 

 * Class RestClient 

 * Wraps HTTP calls using cURL, aimed for accessing and testing RESTful webservice.  

 * By Diogo Souza da Silva <manifesto@manifesto.blog.br> 

 */ 

class RestClient { 



     private $curl ; 

     private $url ; 

     private $response =""; 

     private $headers = array(); 



     private $method="GET"; 

     private $params=null; 

     private $contentType = null; 

     private $file =null; 



     /** 

      * Private Constructor, sets default options 

      */ 

     private function __construct() { 

         $this->curl = curl_init(); 

         curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 

         curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,true); // This make sure will follow redirects 

         curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,false); // This too 

         curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,true); // THis verbose option for extracting the headers 

     } 



     /** 

      * Execute the call to the webservice 

      * @return RestClient 

      */  

     public function execute() { 

         if($this->method === "POST") { 

             curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_POST,true); 

             curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$this->params); 

         } else if($this->method == "GET"){ 

             curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true); 

             $this->treatURL(); 

         } else if($this->method === "PUT") { 

             curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_PUT,true); 

             $this->treatURL(); 

             $this->file = tmpFile(); 

             fwrite($this->file,$this->params); 

             fseek($this->file,0); 

             curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_INFILE,$this->file); 

             curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_INFILESIZE,strlen($this->params)); 

         } else { 

             curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,$this->method); 

         } 

         if($this->contentType != null) { 

             curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-Type: ".$this->contentType)); 

         } 

         curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_URL,$this->url); 

         $r = curl_exec($this->curl); 

         $this->treatResponse($r); // Extract the headers and response 

         return $this ; 

     } 



     /** 

      * Treats URL 

      */ 

     private function treatURL(){ 

         if(is_array($this->params) && count($this->params) >= 1) { // Transform parameters in key/value pars in URL 

             if(!strpos($this->url,'?')) 

                 $this->url .= '?' ; 

             foreach($this->params as $k=>$v) { 

                 $this->url .= "&".urlencode($k)."=".urlencode($v); 

             } 

         } 

        return $this->url; 

     } 



     /* 

      * Treats the Response for extracting the Headers and Response 

      */  

     private function treatResponse($r) { 

        if($r == null or strlen($r) < 1) { 

            return; 

        } 

        $parts  = explode("\n\r",$r); // HTTP packets define that Headers end in a blank line (\n\r) where starts the body

        while(preg_match('@HTTP/1.[0-1] 100 Continue@',$parts[0]) or preg_match("@Moved@",$parts[0])) { 

            // Continue header must be bypass 

            for($i=1;$i<count($parts);$i++) { 

                $parts[$i - 1] = trim($parts[$i]); 

            } 

            unset($parts[count($parts) - 1]); 

        } 

        preg_match("@Content-Type: ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+/?[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)@",$parts[0],$reg);// This extract the content type 

        $this->headers['content-type'] = $reg[1]; 

        preg_match("@HTTP/1.[0-1] ([0-9]{3}) ([a-zA-Z ]+)@",$parts[0],$reg); // This extracts the response header Code and Message 

        $this->headers['code'] = $reg[1]; 

        $this->headers['message'] = $reg[2]; 

        $this->response = ""; 

        for($i=1;$i<count($parts);$i++) {//This make sure that exploded response get back togheter 

            if($i > 1) { 

                $this->response .= "\n\r"; 

            } 

            $this->response .= $parts[$i]; 

        } 

     } 



     /* 

      * @return array 

      */ 

     public function getHeaders() { 

        return $this->headers; 

     } 



     /* 

      * @return string 

      */  

     public function getResponse() { 

         return $this->response ; 

     } 



     /* 

      * HTTP response code (404,401,200,etc) 

      * @return int 

      */ 

     public function getResponseCode() { 

         return (int) $this->headers['code']; 

     } 



     /* 

      * HTTP response message (Not Found, Continue, etc ) 

      * @return string 

      */ 

     public function getResponseMessage() { 

         return $this->headers['message']; 

     } 



     /* 

      * Content-Type (text/plain, application/xml, etc) 

      * @return string 

      */ 

     public function getResponseContentType() { 

         return $this->headers['content-type']; 

     } 



     /** 

      * This sets that will not follow redirects 

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public function setNoFollow() { 

         curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,false); 

         curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,false); 

         return $this; 

     } 



     /** 

      * This closes the connection and release resources 

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public function close() { 

         curl_close($this->curl); 

         $this->curl = null ; 

         if($this->file !=null) { 

             fclose($this->file); 

         } 

         return $this ; 

     } 



     /** 

      * Sets the URL to be Called 

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public function setUrl($url) { 

         $this->url = $url;  

         return $this; 

     } 



     /** 

      * Set the Content-Type of the request to be send 

      * Format like "application/xml" or "text/plain" or other 

      * @param string $contentType 

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public function setContentType($contentType) { 

         $this->contentType = $contentType; 

         return $this; 

     } 



     /** 

      * Set the Credentials for BASIC Authentication 

      * @param string $user 

      * @param string $pass 

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public function setCredentials($user,$pass) { 

         if($user != null) { 

             curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_BASIC); 

             curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"{$user}:{$pass}"); 

         } 

         return $this; 

     } 



     /** 

      * Set the Request HTTP Method 

      * For now, only accepts GET and POST 

      * @param string $method 

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public function setMethod($method) { 

         $this->method=$method; 

         return $this; 

     } 



     /** 

      * Set Parameters to be send on the request 

      * It can be both a key/value par array (as in array("key"=>"value")) 

      * or a string containing the body of the request, like a XML, JSON or other 

      * Proper content-type should be set for the body if not a array 

      * @param mixed $params 

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public function setParameters($params) { 

         $this->params=$params; 

         return $this; 

     } 



     /** 

      * Creates the RESTClient 

      * @param string $url=null [optional] 

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public static function createClient($url=null) { 

         $client = new RestClient ; 

         if($url != null) { 

             $client->setUrl($url); 

         } 

         return $client; 

     } 



     /** 

      * Convenience method wrapping a commom POST call 

      * @param string $url 

      * @param mixed params 

      * @param string $user=null [optional] 

      * @param string $password=null [optional] 

      * @param string $contentType="multpary/form-data" [optional] commom post (multipart/form-data) as default 

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public static function post($url,$params=null,$user=null,$pwd=null,$contentType="multipart/form-data") { 

         return self::call("POST",$url,$params,$user,$pwd,$contentType); 

     } 



     /** 

      * Convenience method wrapping a commom PUT call 

      * @param string $url 

      * @param string $body  

      * @param string $user=null [optional] 

      * @param string $password=null [optional] 

      * @param string $contentType=null [optional]  

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public static function put($url,$body,$user=null,$pwd=null,$contentType=null) { 

         return self::call("PUT",$url,$body,$user,$pwd,$contentType); 

     } 



     /** 

      * Convenience method wrapping a commom GET call 

      * @param string $url 

      * @param array params 

      * @param string $user=null [optional] 

      * @param string $password=null [optional] 

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public static function get($url,array $params=null,$user=null,$pwd=null) { 

         return self::call("GET",$url,$params,$user,$pwd); 

     } 



     /** 

      * Convenience method wrapping a commom delete call 

      * @param string $url 

      * @param array params 

      * @param string $user=null [optional] 

      * @param string $password=null [optional] 

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public static function delete($url,array $params=null,$user=null,$pwd=null) { 

         return self::call("DELETE",$url,$params,$user,$pwd); 

     } 



     /** 

      * Convenience method wrapping a commom custom call 

      * @param string $method 

      * @param string $url 

      * @param string $body  

      * @param string $user=null [optional] 

      * @param string $password=null [optional] 

      * @param string $contentType=null [optional]  

      * @return RestClient 

      */ 

     public static function call($method,$url,$body,$user=null,$pwd=null,$contentType=null) { 

         return self::createClient($url) 

             ->setParameters($body) 

             ->setMethod($method) 

             ->setCredentials($user,$pwd) 

             ->setContentType($contentType) 

             ->execute() 

             ->close(); 

     } 

} 



?>
```

Comment: Please add the code *how* you request the URL using REST in PHP.

Comment: @mario using the code in this post gives me these result .. AA ... i ± i - i i ¨ §

Comment: Well then that's just how the decoded version should look. (And you didn't specify what you actually expected). Anyhow, if this is a HTTP response, you might be lucky with `curl($url)->httpheader("Acccept-Charset: ASCII")->exec()` or something.

Comment: where to use curl($url)->httpheader("Acccept-Charset: ASCII")->exec()     ?

Comment: Ooops, sorry. Your class requires something more cumbersome with curl_setopt somewhere. Just try adding that request header.