# Php Arabic characters are not concatenated correctly

Tags: php, utf-8

This is what I want to achieve:

```
تلر
```

This is the problem:

```
$a = "ت";
$l = "ﻝ";
$z = "ر";

$word = $a.$l.$z;
echo $word;
```

Prints:

```
ت‌ل‌ر
```

while:

```
echo "تلر";
```

prints:

```
تلر
```

Actually there are no white-spaces but if you try this code (remember to allow utf-8) you will see that the letters won't combine. It works when the letters are combined directly. But as I combine then one by one like: `$a.$b.`... they wont combine.

Any ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: I came across this problem before, are you using jquery, jquery ui or any javascript that control your display into the browser ??

Comment: Actually this code is pure PHP. How did you solve it?

Comment: in my case, I was using jquery ui combobox to display arabic options and the error was in the jquery ui library , I removed the <span> tag , I think your problem is a pure client side problem , your php code is correct, try to use another browser and check if your client  side code is alright.

Comment: Is this all that there is to the script?

Comment: Doesn't work in any browsers.

Comment: Tried it in chrome, EI, firfox and it's not working. nofont just normal echo

Comment: Hmm ye, after checking your last edit it doesn't work for me aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Your second single character is U+FEDD while the second character in `تلر` is U+0644. Use the proper characters and it works:

```
$a = "ت";
$l = "ل";
$z = "ر";
var_dump("تلر" === $a.$l.$z);
```

You might want to have a look at [*How to decode Unicode escape sequences like “\u00ed” to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934602/53114)

Comment: You are right. But problem is that if there is no space between `ت` and the next character of it in string it should be automatically converted into the `U+0644`. We can NOT have `U+FEDD` between two characters without spaces.

Comment: I agree with @Arash Milani

Comment: @ArashMilani Well, PHP is not a word processor. It just prints what you tell it to print.

Answer (score 0):

try to make this encoding instead of utf-8

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256 "/>
```

EDIT:

the most popular encoding for arabic language are :

```
      Windows-1256, ISO 8859-6, and UTF-8.
```

EDIT:
 for it will work , you must set your editor also the encoding to `windows-1256` and if u are getting strings from database , you must set encoding for database to `windows-1256` and should work

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Normaly I use: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">. Tried with windows-1256 changed encoding and still no result.