# How do I convert an utf8 string in "\uxxxx" format to latin1?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have to save a JSON formatted string into my latin1 mysql db. In order to be able to use the uft8_encode function, I have to convert the entire array to utf8, and then convert the resultant string back to latin1.

So I tried the following code:

```
    // $context is equal to array('produção' => 'homologação'), for testing purposes
    $context = Helper::getHelper('Util')->encodeUtf8($context); // Encodes key and value with utf8_encode

    $context = json_encode($context); // {"produ\u00e7\u00e3o":"homologa\u00e7\u00e3o"}

    $context = utf8_decode($context); // Still {"produ\u00e7\u00e3o":"homologa\u00e7\u00e3o"}
```

But as you can see, it just doesn't work as I expected. I tried to use Zend_Json library too, but it doesn't work with those chars either.

**To simplify:** I need to encode a latin1 array to JSON, and then insert that JSON in my latin1 db.

Anybody knows how I can do that? A better way to accomplish the same result will be much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing `utf8_decode` on something that is not `utf8`.

JSON encoded content is always ASCII so performing `utf8_decode` will do nothing (ASCII is a subset of UTF8). You must first decode the JSON.

The correct sequence would be:

```
$string = "some UTF8 string";   // utf8
$json = json_encode($string); // json
$utf8 = json_decode($json); // utf8
$latin = utf8_decode($utf8); // latin1
```

Of course, this JSON step here is unnecessary but I'm guessing you're using JSON to transmit or store your data (which is a good idea!).

---

Since you updated the question:

JSON is ASCII so storing it in a latin1 encoded field should be no problem.

If you want your utf8 encoded data to be sent to the client as latin1 then you need to do some encoding conversion, either before you put it in the database or after you pull it out.

My point is that you don't need to do any tricks to store the JSON in the database. This should not be part of the question. At this point it is to me still unclear what you want. The statement:

> To simplify: I need to encode a latin1 array to JSON, and then insert that JSON in my latin1 db.

does not rhyme with your code sample where your input is (I assume) utf8 encoded JSON.

Comment: Note that `utf8_decode` only accepts a string, not an array, as `$context` originally was.

Comment: But that's the problem, I can't decode the JSON. If I do so, I will end with the same array that I had on the beginning of the script. But that information about the ASCII was very useful, I'll try to find an answer. If I do, I'll post here.

Comment: The only valid encodings for JSON are UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32, the default mode of php's `json_encode` is to use `\uxxxx` to keep it in ascii subset, but this might not the case for other json implementations as using the actual characters is just as valid.

Answer (score 0):

I have an latin1 encoded array. I have to encode that array to JSON, and then store that JSON in my also latin1 db. My first problem was that json_encode only accepts utf8 encoded arrays, so I had to encode my entire array to utf8.

But the real problem was my db. When I inserted the JSON, it inserts the literal string, with some "\uxxxx" sequences. I first thought those were just utf8 chars, so I tried to decode them. Obviously, I was wrong.

@Frits' explanation that json_encode's result is pure ascii helped me a lot and made me look at different directions, and I found the solution for my problem.

Since the "\uxxxx" sequences were just ascii, what I really needed was to replace those sequences with the proper utf8 chars, and then decode the entire string.

It's well explained here:
[How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)

I'm particulary not really happy about that solution, but I have a deadline. So, if someone has a better way to do that, please, share with me.

I hope that helps some people in the same situation. Despite its ugliness, it works.