# Unicode character not converted in HTML format

Tags: php, unicode

i am going to elaborate my question in details so that someone help me out.

i have multilingual site. a;; language translation is stored in language ini file with key/value pair e.g. WELCOME=\u0e22\u0e34\u0e19\u0e14\u0e35\u0e15\u0e49\u0e2d\u0e19\u0e23\u0e31\u0e1a in Thai.

when i used parse_ini_file function it will return an array. but without changing the unicode language character in html/readable format.

My concern is that how can i read my language file so that it produce the output in human readable form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, “\u0E23\u0E30\u0E1A\u0E1A\u0E02\u0E31\u0E14\u0E02\u0E49\u0E2D\u0E07” is just a string of characters with no special meaning – it does not denote anything else.

In some programming languages, the string may be treated as containing escape notations for characters. As your question seems to relate to PHP, please check e.g. [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)