# PDO query returns lots of \uXXXX character codes which I can't convert to unicode characters

Tags: php, json, unicode, utf-8, pdo

I have a MySQL database table in which I store the names of countries in different languages, and I can't get the data to display in unicode characters - I can only get \uXXXX codes displayed where the special characters should be.

The query is used in an AJAX request with the results encoded as a JSON object.

Here is the table (truncated):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_countries` (
  `ccode` varchar(2) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `country_en` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `country_fr` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country_de` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country_es` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country_ru` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country_tr` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country_ar` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ccode`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_countries`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_countries` (`ccode`, `country_en`, `country_fr`, `country_de`, `country_es`, `country_ru`, `country_tr`, `country_ar`) VALUES
('AF', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Afganistán', 'Афганистан', 'Afganistan', 'أفغانستان'),
('AX', 'Aland Islands', 'Îles Åland', 'Alandinseln', 'Islas Åland', 'Аландские острова', 'Aland Adaları', 'جزر أولان'),
('AL', 'Albania', 'Albanie', 'Albanien', 'Albania', 'Албания', 'Arnavutluk', 'ألبانيا'),
('DZ', 'Algeria', 'Algérie', 'Algerien', 'Argelia', 'Алжир', 'Cezayir', 'الجزائر'),
('AS', 'American Samoa', 'Samoa américaines', 'Amerikanisch-Samoa', 'Samoa Americana', 'Американское Самоа', 'Amerikan Samoası', 'ساموا الأمريكية');
```

This is the code to create the PDO:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",
    $dbuser,
    $dbpass,
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);

$return_arr = array ();

if ($conn) {
    $ac_term = $_GET['term'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_countries` WHERE `country_en` LIKE :term";
    $result = $conn->prepare ($query);
    $result->bindValue (":term", "%".$ac_term."%");
    $result->execute ();

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = $result->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['country_en'] = $row['country_en'];
        $row_array['country_de'] = $row['country_de'];
        $row_array['country_es'] = $row['country_es'];
        $row_array['country_fr'] = $row['country_fr'];
        $row_array['country_ru'] = $row['country_ru'];
        $row_array['country_tr'] = $row['country_tr'];
        $row_array['country_ar'] = $row['country_ar'];
        $row_array['ccode'] = $row['ccode'];
        array_push ($return_arr, $row_array);
    }
}

unset ($conn);

echo json_encode ($return_arr);
```

At the start of the PHP script is the following line:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

This is the typical output I get if I enter the search term `united%20king`:

```
[{
   "country_en":"United Kingdom",
   "country_de":"Vereinigtes K\u00f6nigreich",
   "country_es":"Reino Unido",
   "country_fr":"Royaume-Uni",
   "country_ru":"\u0412\u0435\u043b\u0438\u043a\u043e\u0431\u0440\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f",
   "country_tr":"Birle\u015fik Krall\u0131k",
   "country_ar":"\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0645\u0644\u0643\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062a\u062d\u062f\u0629",
   "ccode":"GB"
}]
```

In the PHP code, I tried using `htmlentities`, but it *only* showed the special characters for the German output:

```
$row_array['country_de'] = htmlentities ($row['country_de'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

What am I missing? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Sounds like you're reading UTF8 data on a latin1 page. Double check the headers your HTML or json page is sending.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha . Also try running `SET CHARSET 'utf8'` as well, in case your default encoding is not UTF8.

Comment: I am using `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the start of the PHP file to set the character set.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not PDO but regular behavior of json_encode. In modern PHP versions you can turn it off, but it shouldn't be a problem either way.

I have no idea why you wanted to echo raw json out, but usually it is not intended to be echoed directly into HTML but rather used by some JS code. And JS can sort this encoding out. However, to reduce the amount of data, since 5.4 `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag can be used, .

Also let me suggest you to debug your code a little before asking a question.
If you want to check PDO's output, do it for PDO, not for json. Verify every step your program does, to find one which spoils the data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - it's clearly my lack of understanding that has caused this, and [incorrectly] hashing things together from examples/tutorials.

Comment: You're absolutely right - it now seems pretty obvious I should have done that.

Comment: I must have mentioned it that JS will handle these symbols all right

Answer (score 2):

That is perfectly valid *JSON*; these escape sequences are the regular JSON way to encode non-ASCII characters. If you decode it on the client using a regular JSON decoder, you'll end up with the correct characters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I will look into decoding, or getting rid of the JSON part altogether.