# drupal 7 returning image path with Unicode encoding

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

When I upload a file, its path gets printed with Unicode encoding for the forward slash, i.e
`http:\u002F\u002Flocalhost\u002Fsites\u002Fdefault\u002Ffiles\u002F235265.jpg`

what can I do?

Comment: How are you uploading the file? how are you "printing" the path?

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha

Comment: Does this happen just after the upload? Does this happen when the page/image displays in the frontend?