# Code not decode and not print text

Tags: php

```
// in database column name have text 
// 22-10 \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0433\u0434\u0435-\u044
// type row  - text
$test = urldecode(print_r($i['name'], true));
echo $test;
```

*but this code not output text - not decode and not print text ...*

*Tell me please where error?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo json_decode('"' . $i['name']. '"');
```

And result is: `или где-ф` + [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)