# How to understand Json_decode and covert it to save-able format for database

Tags: php, json, facebook, utf8-decode

When I get facebook login token and send it to graph link, it will return a json string, in which I find this type of format:

```
Luy\u1ec7n
```

I don't understand how facebook encode it but how it appears on facebook page actually (Vietnamese) is:

```
Luyện
```

Then I use:

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
```

It becomes: `Luyá»‡n`

How could I change it to the original word `Luyện` ? and save it to my database ?
and then, is it right way to save name to database then later query from database for other checking purposes ?

Comment: You have utf-8 decode in your tags but \u1ec7 is unicode, this calls for unicode decode functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/ should help with that part.

Comment: I just tried but it not work. it returns exactly the same thing: Luyá»‡n

Comment: What you are getting after using `json_decode` _is_ UTF-8, and it _is_ `Luyện`. If you are getting something else _displayed_, that means you are outputting it into a context that does _not_ use UTF-8.

Comment: I output it by echo and display on webpage. Do you mean html or browser does not use UTF-8? How come I still can see Vietnamese on website ?

Comment: @CBroe: I tried to save it to db too and the format I get is still Luyá»‡n. So it is not about display isn't it ?

Comment: No, it is about you not handling the character encoding correctly.

Comment: @CBroe: So which is the correct way to handle it ? Can u post an asnwer pls, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
Just need to put this into my php code: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` then it will display correctly. To save it on DB and display correctly in DB, need to tell the DB also: `$this->link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);mysql_set_charset('utf8', $this->link);`