# how to parse json from string with data have special chars

Tags: php, json

This is my code:

```
<?php
        $a = array('chào','thân','ái','và','quyết','thắng');
    ?>
    <script>
        var abc = '<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>';
    </script>
```

When run and i got abc variable is:

```
var abc = '["ch\u00e0o","th\u00e2n","\u00e1i","v\u00e0","quy\u1ebft","th\u1eafng"]';
```

So, how to convert it's as before? i want to it's become

```
var abc = '["chào","thân","ái","và","quyết","thắng"]';
```

Comment: Why? For any practical purposes those strings are equal.

Answer (score 1):

There might be you're answer here :
[How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)

But why would you translate those escaped sequences, which should be well displayed and correctly translated by php (json_decode) and javascript (JSON.parse) ?

Answer (score 0):

If your php is >= 5.4, you can use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag to encode unicode characters as-is:

```
var abc = '<?php echo json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>';
```

However, the escaped form works just fine and is less error-prone, so I'd suggest that you keep using it.