# UTF8 codes to html in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I have values like

```
Stra\u00c3\u009fe
```

and

```
Aur\u00e9lien
```

I need them transcoded to say Straße or example 2: Aurélien. 
How can I archive this using PHP functions?
The data origins from php_ldap and an Active Directory source if that helps.

Comment: Where did you get the substrings "\u00c3" "\u009f3"

Comment: It's in the value of the street property. The other one is part of the CN and givenname property in the AD

Comment: Ok, those are unicode values then try exploding the unicode foreach(explode('\u', $string) as $new_string)

Comment: And what to do with the result? I need to transform the entire string, not just get the unicode values.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get what you are trying to say. I need to do the transcoding but don't see how. Could you might provide some sort of snippet or function to do so?

Comment: Where are these values coming from to begin with? From a JSON document by any chance?

Comment: $string = "Aur\u00e9lien";


foreach(explode('\u', $string) as $new_string) {
  
  echo html_entity_decode('&#x' . trim($new_string));
    
} but it isn't complete this sort of works for aur value

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it from Unicode to UTF-8 using multi-byte conversion. A simple example would be

```
#source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-char

function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');

function unicode_decode($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $str);
}

$str = unicode_decode('\u00e9');
```