# How do I convert Unicode escape sequences to text in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, unicode-escapes

I have this Unicode sequence: `\u304a\u306f\u3088\u3046\u3054\u3056\u3044\u307e\u3059`. How do I convert it into text?

```
$unicode = '\u304a\u306f\u3088\u3046\u3054\u3056\u3044\u307e\u3059';
```

I tried:

```
echo $utf8-decode(unicode);
```

and I tried:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($unicode , 'US-ASCII', 'UTF-8');
```

and I tried:

```
echo htmlentities($unicode , ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

but none of these functions convert the sequence into the corresponding Japanese text.

Answer (score 12):

The issue here is that the string is *not* unicode. It is an escape sequence used to note down unicode by means of ASCII characters (so 7bit save).

There is a simply trick to use the phps json decoder for this:

```
<?php
$sequence = '\u304a\u306f\u3088\u3046\u3054\u3056\u3044\u307e\u3059';
print_r(json_decode('["'.$sequence.'"]'));
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => おはようございます
)
```

This means you can define a simple convenience function:

```
<?php
$sequence = '\u304a\u306f\u3088\u3046\u3054\u3056\u3044\u307e\u3059';

function decode($payload) {
  return array_pop(json_decode('["'.$payload.'"]'));
}

echo decode($sequence);
```

You want to add error handling and escaping of json specific control characters inside the payload. This simply example is just meant to point you into the right direction...

Have fun!

Comment: This doesn't work in case input string has double quotes

Comment: @Oleg It is actually mentioned in the answer that one wants to add error handling and escaping in the solution...

Answer (score 6):

Transliterator class from intl extension can handle the convertion with its [predefined Hex-Any identifier](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general):

```
$in = '\u304a\u306f\u3088\u3046\u3054\u3056\u3044\u307e\u3059';
$out = transliterator_create('Hex-Any')->transliterate($in);
var_dump($out); # string(27) "おはようございます"
```

Comment: Thx man, you are life saver. I was converting fonts in Laravel, but laravel give me only unicode font..Your method help me alot.But it need to install php extension.

Answer (score 3):

```
$unicode = '\u304a\u306f\u3088\u3046\u3054\u3056\u3044\u307e\u3059';
$json = sprintf('"%s"',$unicode); # build json string

$utf8_str = json_decode ( $json, true ); # json decode
echo $utf8_str; # おはようございます
```

See [Json string](http://www.json.org/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### PHP 7+

As of PHP 7, you can use the [Unicode codepoint escape syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax) to do this.

`echo "\u{304a}\u{306f}\u{3088}\u{3046}\u{3054}\u{3056}\u{3044}\u{307e}\u{3059}";` outputs `おはようございます`.

Answer (score 0):

The json_decode didn't work on my string, maybe because of double quotes?
The following worked:

```
$payload = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}, $payload);// "\お\は\よ\う\ご\ざ\い\ま\す"
$payload=str_replace('\\',"",$payload); // "おはようございます"
```

I suppose the first command can be improve, not to leave "\", I didn't know how, so I just removed all the "\" with the str_replace.

Comment: It is important that if you copy-paste something that you say where you got it from. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934602/2943403