# php how to decode a text file that contains chars like \u0003c?

Tags: php, curl

When I run

```
$result = exec("curl someURL");
```

I got results that contains \u0003 etc.. chars:

> "d":"\u003c?xml version=\"1.0\"?\u003e\u003cArrayOfAnnoncePresentation
>   xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
>   xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"\u003e\u003cPageCount\u003e\u003cPageCount\u003e25\u003c/PageCount\u003e\u003c/PageCount\u003e\u003cAnnoncePresentation\u003e\u003cTitre\u003e3garages\u003c/Titre\u003e\u003cLienDetail\u003e/

How can I decode that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)

Comment: how about `json_decode`