# php converting unknown symbols to the known symbols in url

Tags: php, url, hex, decode

Converting unknown symbols in url ,

like this

```
https://r4---sn-hgn7zn7r.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes\u0026id\u003d376b916e4a3c65b1\u0026itag\u003d22\u0026source\u003dwebdrive\u0026app\u003dtexmex\u0026ip\u003d109.110.116.1\u0026ipbits\u003d8\u0026expire\u003d1456065477\u0026sparams\u003drequiressl%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire\u0026signature\u003d5C06093099C3B4A7DE28AF323E2E15AC7DE5BEEE.758E1110B23CD41EA7E246DE2564ABE5368431FE\u0026key\u003dck2\u0026mm\u003d30\u0026mn\u003dsn-hgn7zn7r\u0026ms\u003dnxu\u0026mt\u003d1456050981\u0026mv\u003dm\u0026nh\u003dIgpwcjAyLm1yczAyKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE\u0026pl\u003d22
```

to real link,
like this

```
https://r4---sn-hgn7zn7r.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=376b916e4a3c65b1&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=109.110.116.1&ipbits=8&expire=1456065477&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=5C06093099C3B4A7DE28AF323E2E15AC7DE5BEEE.758E1110B23CD41EA7E246DE2564ABE5368431FE&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-hgn7zn7r&ms=nxu&mt=1456050981&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAyLm1yczAyKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=22
```

i have no idea how convert it ,

i use this website to convert the link 
[DDecode - Hex,Octal,HTML Decode](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=583a1e57fe839fca6c27814a639419ce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you have to convert unicode escape sequences like *"\uxxxx"* into utf8 characters.
Use `preg_repalce_callback` function to replace all matched escape sequences with the respective utf8 character.
In the callback function we are using [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function which will pack the initial HEX string to binary string, then it will convert that binary order(*'UCS-2BE*') into *UTF-8* equivalent with [mb-convert-encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

```
$str = "https://r4---sn-hgn7zn7r.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl\u003dyes\u0026id\u003d376b916e4a3c65b1\u0026itag\u003d22\u0026source\u003dwebdrive\u0026app\u003dtexmex\u0026ip\u003d109.110.116.1\u0026ipbits\u003d8\u0026expire\u003d1456065477\u0026sparams\u003drequiressl%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire\u0026signature\u003d5C06093099C3B4A7DE28AF323E2E15AC7DE5BEEE.758E1110B23CD41EA7E246DE2564ABE5368431FE\u0026key\u003dck2\u0026mm\u003d30\u0026mn\u003dsn-hgn7zn7r\u0026ms\u003dnxu\u0026mt\u003d1456050981\u0026mv\u003dm\u0026nh\u003dIgpwcjAyLm1yczAyKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE\u0026pl\u003d22";

$str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}, rawurldecode($str));

echo $str;
// the output:
https://r4---sn-hgn7zn7r.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=376b916e4a3c65b1&itag=22&source=webdrive&app=texmex&ip=109.110.116.1&ipbits=8&expire=1456065477&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=5C06093099C3B4A7DE28AF323E2E15AC7DE5BEEE.758E1110B23CD41EA7E246DE2564ABE5368431FE&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-hgn7zn7r&ms=nxu&mt=1456050981&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAyLm1yczAyKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=22
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be "Unicode Escape Sequences for Latin 1 Characters" (see http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/actionscript/excerpts/as3-cookbook/appendix.html).

A quick search didn't find any native library for decoding this in PHP, but it should be straightforward to decode the characters you're most likely to encounter that need decoding (& and = specifically).

Here's a SO solution to doing it from 5 years ago: [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)