# PHP + Twitter - Why twitter return strange characters in the tweet text?

Tags: php, twitter, special-characters, twitter-oauth

Why do I get strange characters in my twitter tweets?

For example:

> RT @FrankPasquale: â€œFar from being a superstate, the ECâ€™s
>   bureaucracy is tiny--25,000 people for an EU population of 500
>   million" [https://tâ](https://t%C3%A2)€¦

Especially **[https://tâ](https://t%C3%A2)€¦** - it is not a valid link/ url at all!

Follow this [guide](http://iag.me/socialmedia/build-your-first-twitter-app-using-php-in-8-easy-steps/), below is my code how I get the twitter tweet from an user timeline:

```
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "xxx",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxx",
    'consumer_key' => "xxx",
    'consumer_secret' => "xxx"
);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

$requestMethod = "GET";

$getfield = '?screen_name=xxxx&count=6';

$string = json_decode(
    $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
            ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
            ->performRequest(), $assoc = TRUE
    );

if (isset($string["errors"]) && $string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {
    echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3>
          <p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p>
          <p><em>" . $string[errors][0]["message"] . "</em></p>";
    exit();
}

foreach($string as $items) {
    echo "Time and Date of Tweet: ".$items['created_at']."<br />";
    echo "Tweet: ". $items['text']."<br />";
    echo "Tweeted by: ". $items['user']['name']."<br />";
    echo "Screen name: ". $items['user']['screen_name']."<br />";
    echo "Followers: ". $items['user']['followers_count']."<br />";
    echo "Friends: ". $items['user']['friends_count']."<br />";
    echo "Listed: ". $items['user']['listed_count']."<br /><br />";
}
```

Any ideas why and how I can fix it?

**EDIT:**

If I try this:

```
htmlentities($items['text'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

I get this:

> RT @FrankPasquale: “Far from being a superstate, the EC’s bureaucracy
>   is tiny--25,000 people for an EU population of 500 million" https://t…

The link **https://t…** is totally broken!

I also have set my html to:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

But I still get this kind of links:

https://t…

Which is totally broken!

EDIT 2:

The problem is coming from twitter json:

```
{"created_at":"Fri Jun 24 14:28:16 +0000 2016","id":xxx,"id_str":"xxxx","text":"RT @muslimgirl: The people who invaded & colonized the world decided they wanted independence from its consequences
#BrexitVote\nhttps:\/\/t.c\u2026"
```

If you look at `#BrexitVote\nhttps:\/\/t.c\u2026` that is the bug.

How can fix that?

Comment: Check the character encoding of your PHP/HTML page. It should probably be UTF-8, and not something else.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware please see my edit above. The result is now even stranger!

Comment: No, I was talking about the whole page, not any particular string in PHP. Check the page character encoding in your browser. Also see: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

Comment: I did that on the whole page as well.

Comment: And you got rid of the `htmlentities()`? Is the page now HTML5 and UTF-8? Check it in your browser. Usually under 'page info' in the menu. Note that `<meta charset="UTF-8">` will only work if your page is HTML5.

Comment: `And you got rid of the htmlentities()?` - yes I did.

Comment: `Usually under 'page info' in the menu` can't find  'page info' ...

Comment: Well, since I don't know what browser your are using, I cannot tell where it is in yours.

Comment: I am using chrome.

Comment: but i have the html5 tags in my page already: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tweets</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>`

Comment: That does look like the right tags for a HTML5/UTF-8 page. You can find the encoding here: Chrome -> use hamburger menu on the right -> More Tools... -> Encoding -> here it is.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. Yes I have found it and it is /UTF-8 .

Comment: I think it might the problem from the tweet text itself.

Comment: That's possible. You could `var_dump()` the argument you give to `json_decode()` (so not the returned value of this function!) and see what that looks like.

Comment: oh I know why - it is the json! `{"created_at":"Fri Jun 24 14:28:16 +0000 2016","id":xxxx,"id_str":"xxx","text":"RT @muslimgirl: The people who invaded & colonized the world decided they wanted independence from its consequences #BrexitVote\nhttps:\/\/t.c\u2026"`

Comment: look at this `#BrexitVote\nhttps:\/\/t.c\u2026`

Comment: That's normal. `\n` is a new line, `\/` is a slash, `\u2026` just means it's a UTF-8 encoded character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm This is called 'escaping'. `json_decode()` is supposed to correctly decode this.

Comment: `json_decode() is supposed to correctly decode this` but it does not, doesn it?

Comment: That was an assumption on my part... perhaps not. perhaps you need to do that yourself.

Comment: even `https://t.cu2026` is not a working link at all. i still think that it is part of twitter bug.

Comment: I doubt that Twitter has bugs like that. perhaps you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563 to decode the encoded `\u' characters?