# Emoji from android to web

Tags: php, android, emoji

I have a android app, which messages workds with emoji. Saved message with emojis is diaplayed ok on android after fetching from mysql via json.
Now I want to display same message with emojis on web script.
Found JS lib https://github.com/iamcal/js-emoji but cant make it work.
Anyone has a ready to use implementation of it?
Sample db record look like this:

```
Unii \uD83D\uDE02\uD83D\uDE03\uD83D\uDE2E\uD83D\uDE25\uD83D\uDE23\uD83D\uDE0F
```

These are android emojis. Hot make the work on web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The basic configuration from https://github.com/iamcal/js-emoji is enough to make js script to work. The problem was the string encoding. Android uses "Unicode escape sequences" to store specials characters in strings. It works great on mobile, but php has issues with it. Therefore we need to convert Unicode escape sequences with php working version. The converted version of previous db rec

```
Unii \ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude03\ud83d\ude2e\ud83d\ude25\ud83d\ude23\ud83d\ude0f
```

Php convert functions can be found @ [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)

Answer (score 0):

First of all coping files will not make it work ;) you need also do some configuration:

first of all download that repo

- run **npm install** in main directory
- run **bower install** in main directory
- now we need to run some grunt task but before that **make sure that you have copied this  - https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data/tree/6daffc10d8e8fd06b80ec24c9bdcb65218f71563 to emoji-data folder** in downloaded-repo-location/build/emoji-data
- also copy that content of that whole emoji-data (https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data/tree/6daffc10d8e8fd06b80ec24c9bdcb65218f71563) to **C:\js-emoji\build\emoji-data**
- now in demo.htm (which is placed in mainfolder/demo/demo.htm change jquery linkage to  an also make sure that this line is placed above ""
- run "grunt" from console.
- check if in downloaded-repo-root/lib/emoji.js in line 520 you have listed emojis ;)
- run demo.htm in browser

Basically check browser console if it has any errors. Most common erros is that there will be en empty **emoji.prototype.data on line 519 in emoji.js** file - so you need to be sure the **grunt** task finishes correctly without errors.