# How to decode this "\ud835\udcdf\ud835\udcea"

Tags: php, unicode, decode

Ive been trying to decode this for a long while, I need to be able to decode this:

`\ud835\udcdf\ud835\udcea\ud835\udcfd\ud835\udcfb\ud835\udcf2\ud835\udcec\ud835\udcf2\ud835\udcea`

Into this: ""

What encoding is this? 
Can `html_entity_decode` do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)

Comment: Just tried that post, didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
<?php

$str = "\ud835\udcdf\ud835\udcea\ud835\udcfd\ud835\udcfb\ud835\udcf2\ud835\udcec\ud835\udcf2\ud835\udcea";
echo json_decode('"'.$str.'"');

?>
```

Comment: NICE!! Thank you soo much! I've spent hours on this and it was that simple :D Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: Huh, really?  Does mark as solution work? (And it helps future users finding the post).

Comment: Need to wait another minute before i can mark it as solved :)

Comment: `echo json_decode('"'.'\ud835\udcdf\ud835\udcea\ud835\udcfd\ud835\udcfb\ud835'.'"');` not working at all.