# How to convert JavaScript code to its PHP equivalent?

Tags: javascript, php, code-conversion

I have js code:

```js
var b = "aHR0cDovL3d3dy5oZHpvZy5jb20vZ2V0X2ZpbGUvМS84Y2Е5МTЕ4ZmМyNmVkNTk0ZmI5Yzc2ZWI2Y2Y2YWVmМС85NDАwМС85NDU4Ny85NDU4Ny5tcDQvP3RpbWU9МjАxNzА5МjYyМDIxNDYmcz05МTUzZmNmYjАyOTUyOWQxY2JhZTВkYzNkY2ZhODVmZiZicj0xODЕ1JmQ9МTcwNyZmPXZpZGVvLm0zdTg~";
var f = "\u0410\u0412\u0421D\u0415FGHIJKL\u041cNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.,~".indexOf(b.charAt(0));
document.write(f);
```

It return 26. 
And I convert js code to php code:

```
$url = 'aHR0cDovL3d3dy5oZHpvZy5jb20vZ2V0X2ZpbGUvМS84Y2Е5МTЕ4ZmМyNmVkNTk0ZmI5Yzc2ZWI2Y2Y2YWVmМС85NDАwМС85NDU4Ny85NDU4Ny5tcDQvP3RpbWU9МjАxNzА5МjYyМDIxNDYmcz05МTUzZmNmYjАyOTUyOWQxY2JhZTВkYzNkY2ZhODVmZiZicj0xODЕ1JmQ9МTcwNyZmPXZpZGVvLm0zdTg~';
$str = "\u0410\u0412\u0421D\u0415FGHIJKL\u041cNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.,~";
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($match) {
return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}, $str);
$f = strpos($str, $url[0]);
echo $f;
```

But it return 31. Why?

Comment: look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php to replace `String.fromCharCode`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: can you please tell which function you struggling find alternate in php ?

Comment: It use to decode string

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, I know.

Comment: Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

'\u0421' in JavaScript is representative of a character. In Php however, it is not. That's why JavaScript is showing fewer spaces between index 0 and the first instance of 'a'.

To remedy this... I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for... [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)

Comment: Thanks, i used it but php still return 31, not return 26. Why?

Comment: You can use this instead actually...  $str = json_decode('"' . $str . '"'); 
 var_dump($str);  $f = strpos($str, $url[0]);

Comment: Thank @John, can you help me convert: 64 != g && (c += String.fromCharCode(e)); to php?